# How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, properties, count, key

What's the fastest way to count the number of keys/properties of an object? Is it possible to do this without iterating over the object?  I.e., without doing:

```
var count = 0;
for (k in myobj) if (myobj.hasOwnProperty(k)) ++count;
```

(Firefox did provide a magic `__count__` property, but this was removed somewhere around version 4.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array

Comment: a performance benchmark for different ways: http://jsben.ch/#/oSt2p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: If you need to count mappings, that might mean it’s time to consider **`Map`**.

Answer (score 3159, accepted):

To do this in any *[ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition)-compatible environment*, such as [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), Chrome, [Internet Explorer 9+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9), Firefox 4+, or Safari 5+:

```js
Object.keys(obj).length
```

- [Browser compatibility](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)
- [Object.keys documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (includes a method you can add to non-ES5 browsers)

Comment: Not just Node.js, but any environment that supports ES5

Comment: BTW... just ran some tests... this method runs in O(n) time.  A for loop isn't much worse than this method. ** sad face **
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956554/efficiently-counting-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: @BMiner that's a shame, but this approach still has the advantages of concision and clarity.

Comment: It must be O(n) since it's creating a new list of size n.  i.e. `var o = {a: 1, b: 2}; Object.keys(o).slice(1)` doesn't affect o.  I still don't think there is a better answer than this though!

Comment: -1 (-200 if I could) This not only iterates through the object but also creates a whole new array with all its keys, so it completely fails at answering the question.

Comment: It seems much faster than doing the for (at least on Chrome 25): http://jsperf.com/count-elements-in-object

Comment: @fserb Interesting! Maybe some optimisation? And the FF "loop 2" result is an interesting outlier--5x faster than anything else.

Comment: @fserb yeah but only if you repeatedly call it... basically you test the run time of a function call. added a cached test, only calling Object.keys once. same speed.

Comment: @mjs likely a erroneous optimization, no longer faster on ffx 21.

Comment: @ceram1 Are you sure about that? Does the return value of `map.keys()` reflect changes made to `map` after the `.keys()` call?

Comment: @ceram1  Java != javascript ;  You seem to be confusing the two.

Comment: @ceram1 In this case, people only care how javascript _is_ implementing the `Object.keys()` method, regardless of what is "normal".  Pointing out how Java does something has no bearing on this conversation.

Comment: @TimTisdall Hmm.. I think it can confuse newbies, so I'll delete comments about java. Object.keys . According to spec http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.14 . It doesn't specified if it's clone or original. In chrome, it said "since the result is mutable we have to create a fresh clone on each invocation." Sorry for confusing, but it's okay to use Object.keys as fixed array is very fast.

Comment: This question is a few years old now, but for anyone who is looking at the speed test results above, I ran the exact same test using lodash instead of underscore: http://jsperf.com/count-elements-in-object/12  lodash kicks underscore's ass

Comment: @JakeSellers: I must be mising something obvious,but what is the difference between 'underscore' and 'lodash' ? besides, on my platform both variants perform roughly identical ( both slightly above 18 kOps/s ).

Comment: @collapsar, I won't go way into it, but one of the devs that was working on underscore didn't like how inconsistently the underscore functions were being developed(how they work, what they retuarn, etc) and decided to create his own lib called lodash(ba-dum-tish).  Its generally faster, has more features, and is just plain better(IMO).  If you're so inclined you can find discussions(arguments) between the two lead devs on several different boards that give insite into why the split happened.

Comment: Even though this creates a whole new array, it's still quick.  This is probably because it is implemented in native C or C++, so even though it may not be as efficient, since C and C++ are so much faster intrinsically it still may be faster

Comment: Solved a similar issue in couchdb too:
       "listByUniversityId": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n if(doc.type === 'ghgReport')\n  \temit(doc.universityId,Object.keys(doc.reports).length);\n}"
       }

Comment: I am having a hard explaining my question, but lets say I have a function prototype that sort of extends my object and I only want to count the properties that have normal values (EX: string, int)

Comment: Not useful for traversing parsed JSON objects.

Comment: @GetFree  Why so many thumbs up? This is definitely the fastest way in terms of coding. No extra methods or libraries required. In terms of code speed, apparently it's not too bad either. Not a complete fail at all.

Comment: This iterates over the object. The question specifically is asking for solutions that do not iterate over the object.

Comment: @GetFree Depending on how a JS environment implements objects, counting the number of properties that an object has might unavoidably be an O(n) operation with respect to the number of properties. If so, this would mean that iterating over all of the properties, explicitly or not, *is* the most efficient approach. (I don't know how JS environments implement objects, so this is speculation on my part.)

Comment: If you have a list of potential keys, it is 10x faster to try all keys.
I was quite surprised, but the tests prove it:
https://jsperf.com/count-elements-in-object/22

Comment: It doesn't have to iterate over the object(it just does on some vm's).  But its thumb upped because it works and is solution for most people who come across this question from google looking for a quick way to get a count of the keys. The people thumbing it up don't really care what happens under the hood.

Comment: @GetFree then what's the the optimal approach?

Comment: Of course we care if what is under the hood has issues! The optimal approach is to use babel to compile efficiency or rely on V8, Servo, or whatever supported browser engine to perform optimizations. If you find inefficiency, file a bug there. Lets also put an end to micro-profiling (it is fine for it to run a slower at first while it performs run-time optimizations).

Comment: When *you* are in control of the object, (your own code is the only thing adding properties to it), then you could increment a separate counter variable whenever you add a new property, or decrement when you remove a property.  This should be faster than any solution related to keys().  It's not an "atomic" thread-safe operation, but for many situations it's fine.  And certainly fast.

Comment: @GetFree One O(1) alternative that I can think of is to make a wrapper class of Object and cont every time something gets added or removed. Also you could write a transpiler that constructs this class from a syntax sugar. Let me know if there are better ideas. P.S. There are a lot of O(1) improvement that can be made to the current version of JS, including this one and selecting randomly from an object etc. I sincerely hope that these features will be available in the next version of ES and that the abusing of Object.keys() will stop being necessary.

Answer (score 164):

You could use this code:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = function (obj) {
        var keys = [],
            k;
        for (k in obj) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
}
```

Then you can use this in older browsers as well:

```
var len = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the check `(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k))`?

Comment: @styfle If you use a _for_ loop to iterate over the object's properties, you also get the properties in the prototype chain. That's why checking `hasOwnProperty` is necessary. It only returns properties set on the object itself.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because you use `call` on `hasOwnProperty` instead of just using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(obj, k)`. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: @styfle To make it simpler you could just write `obj.hasOwnProperty(k)` (I actually did this in my original post, but updated it later). `hasOwnProperty` is available on every object because it is part of the `Object`'s prototype, but in the rare event that this method would be removed or overridden you might get unexpected results. By calling it from `Object.prototype` it makes it little more robust. The reason for using `call` is because you want to invoke the method on `obj` instead of on the prototype.

Comment: Would not it better to use this version ? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @XavierDelamotte You are absolutely correct. While my version works, it is very basic and ment as an example. Mozilla's code is more safe. (PS: Your link is also in the accepted answer)

Comment: for the new-comer to js looking at this answer... DO NOT ever modify default javascript classes, ever!

Comment: @Dmitry This code does not modify a default class. It only adds a shim to mimic standard functionality if it does not exists.

Comment: @RenaatDeMuynck and now tell me what happens when method named 'keys' becomes a standard in ecmaScript? And while you are at it think about what specification it might have...

Comment: @DmitryMatveev It's already a standard (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14). This code adds standard behavior where it's missing.

Comment: @RenaatDeMuynck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: @DmitryMatveev Perhaps I am not making my point clear: It is not a good practice to extend native object protoypes *except* when implementing missing standard features (read the following carefully: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes). So as I stated in my previous comment: `Object.keys` *is* now a standard en *should* be implemented in older browser in this manner. I would suggest to read everything carefully once more before you comment on this again...

Comment: This gives same result as: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length`; much simpler.

Comment: @Wilt Actually, there is a difference. As stated in [@BenderTheOffender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377849/288264), `getOwnPropertyNames` also counts non-enumerable properties. It all depends on the needs of the OP. But since he didn't specify, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length` is probably better.

Answer (score 143):

If you are using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you can use [_.size](http://underscorejs.org/#size) ([thanks douwe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip#comment7517359_6019605)):

```
_.size(obj)
```

Alternatively you can also use [_.keys](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) which might be clearer for some:

```
_.keys(obj).length
```

I highly recommend Underscore.js. It's a tight library for doing lots of basic things. Whenever possible, they match [ECMAScript 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition) and defer to the native implementation.

Otherwise I support [Avi Flax' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip/4889658#4889658). I edited it to add a link to the [MDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) documentation which includes the keys() method you can add to non-ECMAScript 5 browsers.

Comment: If you use underscore.js then you should use _.size instead. The good thing is that if you somehow switch from array to object or vice versa the result stays the same.

Comment: And from my understanding lodash is generally better than underscore (though they do similar things).

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham if I recall correctly, lodash is originally a fork of underscore...

Comment: `_.keys(obj).length` worked best for me, because my return object is sometimes a plain string with no properties within it. `_.size(obj)` gives me back the length of the string, while `_.keys(obj).length` returns 0.

Comment: **O(n) complexity**. Lodash and Underscore use `Object.keys` internally. Underscore also copies every key into an array inside a `for..in` loop if `Object.keys` is not defined.

Answer (score 101):

Here are some performance tests for three methods;

https://jsperf.com/get-the-number-of-keys-in-an-object

### Object.keys().length

**20,735** operations per second

It is very simple and compatible and runs fast *but* expensive, because it creates a new array of keys, which then gets thrown away.

```
return Object.keys(objectToRead).length;
```

### Loop through the keys

**15,734** operations per second

```
let size=0;
for(let k in objectToRead) {
  size++
}
return size;
```

It is slightly slower, but nowhere near the memory usage, so it is probably better if you're interested in optimising for mobile or other small machines.

### Using Map instead of Object

**953,839,338** operations per second

```
return mapToRead.size;
```

Basically, Map tracks its own size, so we're just returning a number field. It is far, far faster than any other method. If you have control of the object, convert them to maps instead.

Comment: "Using Map instead of Object" - this is the most helpful suggestion on this page.

Comment: MDN has a useful comparison of `Object` vs. `Map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map. The downside seems to be lack of native support for `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Wrappers end up converting `Map` -> `Object` for `JSON` functions, so it kind of defeats the purpose for content that only exists to be serialized/deserialized. If serialization and actual Object functionality are not needed, `Map` appears to be the superior choice.

Comment: Sadly, looks like jsperf is down. Is there any chance, if it comes back up again, someone could edit the benchmark code into the answer? I tried to reproduce on another site (jsbench.me, though without a login, I can't share the tests), testing with a single fixed object with 26 keys, for lowercase `a` through `z`, and, on Edge 113, running on a thin client setup (so the work was done on pretty beefy, but shared, servers), `Object.keys().length` had throughput over 5x greater than the for loop, and over 10x any for loop variant using `hasOwnProperty` (cached or uncached, branching or not).

Comment: Using a `Map` instead was in turn nearly twice the throughput of the `Object.keys().length` solution, so the rankings were unchanged, but the *degree* of success was quite different; `Map` was better, but only around 2x, not 50x better. `Object.keys().length` was twice as good as the `for` loop, not just a third higher throughput. But of course, my microbenchmark (reusing the same object/`Map` over and over) may allow JS engines to optimize when they shouldn't, and the relative performance would obviously depend on the size of the object/`Map` (since all but the `Map` solution are `O(n)`).

Comment: You should provide measurements for different n

Comment: If you're converting an existing Object into a Map, you'll be iterating through the Object to do so. It should be specified that you need to "initialize them as maps" instead of "convert them to maps" to get the stated performance benefits.

Answer (score 97):

The standard Object implementation ([ES5.1 Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)) does not require an `Object` to track its number of keys/properties, so there should be no standard way to determine the size of an `Object` without explicitly or implicitly iterating over its keys.

So here are the most commonly used alternatives:

#### 1. ECMAScript's Object.keys()

`Object.keys(obj).length;` Works by *internally* iterating over the keys to compute a temporary array and returns its length.

- **Pros** - Readable and clean syntax. No library or custom code required except a shim if native support is unavailable
- **Cons** - Memory overhead due to the creation of the array.

#### 2. Library-based solutions

Many library-based examples elsewhere in this topic are useful idioms in the context of their library. From a performance viewpoint, however, there is nothing to gain compared to a perfect no-library code since all those library methods actually encapsulate either a for-loop or ES5 `Object.keys` (native or shimmed).

#### 3. Optimizing a for-loop

The **slowest part** of such a for-loop is generally the `.hasOwnProperty()` call, because of the function call overhead. So when I just want the number of entries of a JSON object, I just skip the `.hasOwnProperty()` call if I know that no code did nor will extend  `Object.prototype`.

Otherwise, your code could be very slightly optimized by making `k` local (`var k`) and by using prefix-increment operator (`++count`) instead of postfix.

```
var count = 0;
for (var k in myobj) if (myobj.hasOwnProperty(k)) ++count;
```

Another idea relies on caching the `hasOwnProperty` method:

```
var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
var count = 0;
for (var k in myobj) if (hasOwn.call(myobj, k)) ++count;
```

Whether this is faster or not on a given environment is a question of benchmarking. Very limited performance gain can be expected anyway.

Comment: Why would `var k in myobj` boost performance? As far as I know, only functions declare new scope in JavaScript. Are in-loops an exception to this rule?

Comment: Is this faster?
`for (var k in myobj) hasOwn.call(myobj, k) && ++count;`
i.e. replacing the if statement with a simple &&?

Comment: Last thing you can do with: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length`; much simpler.

Comment: @HamzaKubba: That would be logically exactly equivalent; I doubt any JS engine would optimize either of them differently. It's *very* slightly possible that `for (var k in myobj) count += myobj.hasOwnProperty(k);` might do better, as it would be replacing a logical test-and-branch with branch-free (in the sense of unpredictable branches) code, but that all depends on whether the engine pays any price to convert from bool to int and whether unconditional writes to `count` even when it's not an own-prop matter. But at least in testing on Edge 113, it's *slightly* slower with `+=`.

Comment: And just for my own edification, `hasOwn.call(myobj, k) && ++count` was *slightly* slower than `if (hasOwn.call(myobj, k)) ++count`. A trivial difference (and could easily be timing jitter), but it's definitely not *better*.

Answer (score 36):

If you are actually running into a performance problem I would suggest wrapping the calls that add/remove properties to/from the object with a function that also increments/decrements an appropriately named (size?) property.

You only need to calculate the initial number of properties once and move on from there. If there isn't an actual performance problem, don't bother. Just wrap that bit of code in a function `getNumberOfProperties(object)` and be done with it.

Comment: @hitautodestruct Because he offers a solution.

Comment: @crush This answer seems to suggest things to do rather than give a direct solution.

Comment: @hitautodestruct it suggests an answer: incrementing/decrementing an encapsulated count with the add/remove methods. There is another answer exactly like this below. The only difference is, Confusion did not offer any code. Answers are not mandated to provide code solutions only.

Comment: @crush Right you are, but they should not start with a question. Fixed :)

Comment: it may not be perfect ... but compared with the other "answers" this may be the best solution for some situations

Comment: So far this is the only solution I see that is O(1) constant time performance complexity, and therefore is the only solution that Answers the Question detail of "without iterating" and should therefore be the tru Accepted Answer.  Most if not all other answers don't answer that, because they offer an O(n) linear time performance complexity; that's the case also for the 1-line solutions that call something like a .keys() function, as such function calls are O(n).

Answer (score 30):

As answered in a previous answer: `Object.keys(obj).length`

But: as we have now a real [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class in ES6, I would [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600157/maps-vs-objects-in-es6-when-to-use) to use it instead of using the properties of an object.

```
const map = new Map();
map.set("key", "value");
map.size; // THE fastest way
```

Comment: What answer in particular? Can you link to it (normal linking, not a naked link)?

Comment: I was just referring to `Object.keys(obj).length` https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889658/532695

Answer (score 30):

**this works for both, Arrays and Objects**

```
//count objects/arrays
function count(obj){
        return Object.keys(obj).length
     }
```

**count objects/arrays with a Loop**

```
function count(obj){
        var x=0;
        for(k in obj){
          x++;
         }
      return x;
     }
```

**count objects/arrays or also the length of a String**

```
function count(obj){
        if (typeof (obj) === 'string' || obj instanceof String)
        {
          return obj.toString().length;   
        }
        return Object.keys(obj).length
     }
```

Answer (score 20):

As [stated by Avi Flax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip/4889658#4889658),

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

will do the trick for all enumerable properties on your object, but to also include the non-enumerable properties, you can instead use the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. Here's the difference:

```
var myObject = new Object();

Object.defineProperty(myObject, "nonEnumerableProp", {
  enumerable: false
});
Object.defineProperty(myObject, "enumerableProp", {
  enumerable: true
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject).length); //outputs 2
console.log(Object.keys(myObject).length); //outputs 1

console.log(myObject.hasOwnProperty("nonEnumerableProp")); //outputs true
console.log(myObject.hasOwnProperty("enumerableProp")); //outputs true

console.log("nonEnumerableProp" in myObject); //outputs true
console.log("enumerableProp" in myObject); //outputs true
```

As [stated here](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), this has the same browser support as `Object.keys`.

However, in most cases, you might not want to include the nonenumerables in these type of operations, but it's always good to know the difference ;)

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, you were the only one here...

Answer (score 17):

To iterate on [Avi Flax' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip/4889658#4889658), *Object.keys(obj).length* is correct for an object that doesn’t have functions tied to it.

Example:

```
obj = {"lol": "what", owo: "pfft"};
Object.keys(obj).length; // should be 2
```

versus

```
arr = [];
obj = {"lol": "what", owo: "pfft"};
obj.omg = function(){
    _.each(obj, function(a){
        arr.push(a);
    });
};
Object.keys(obj).length; // should be 3 because it looks like this
/* obj === {"lol": "what", owo: "pfft", omg: function(){_.each(obj, function(a){arr.push(a);});}} */
```

Steps to avoid this:

1. do not put functions in an object that you want to count the number of keys in
2. use a separate object or make a new object specifically for functions (if you want to count how many functions there are in the file using `Object.keys(obj).length`)

Also, yes, I used the `_` or [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) module from Node.js in my example.

Documentation can be found [here](http://underscorejs.org/) as well as its source on GitHub and various other information.

And finally a lodash implementation https://lodash.com/docs#size

`_.size(obj)`

Comment: In response to your comments about `Array(obj).length`:
It doesn't work.
[http://jsfiddle.net/Jhy8M/](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhy8M/)

Comment: yeah i looked into it a bit more im going to end up removing this answer if possible or just editing it all together

Comment: I'm not seeing that this has anything to do with functions, for one, and in Chrome I don't see this behavior at all.  I would suspect this may have had to do with the default behavior of [Object.defineProperty():enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) which is `false`, though I've not yet found any documentation on how `var obj = { a: true, b: true }` may differ from `var obj = {}; obj.a = true; obj.b = true;` or simply if a different interpretation/semantics of the W3 has been adopted by Chrome.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not aware of any way to do this. However, to keep the iterations to a minimum, you could try checking for the existence of `__count__` and if it doesn't exist (i.e., not Firefox) then you could iterate over the object and define it for later use, e.g.:

```
if (myobj.__count__ === undefined) {
  myobj.__count__ = ...
}
```

This way, any browser supporting `__count__` would use that, and iterations would only be carried out for those which don't. If the count changes and you can't do this, you could always make it a function:

```
if (myobj.__count__ === undefined) {
  myobj.__count__ = function() { return ... }
  myobj.__count__.toString = function() { return this(); }
}
```

This way, any time you reference myobj.`__count__` the function will fire and recalculate.

Comment: Note that `Object.prototype.__count__` is being removed in Gecko 1.9.3:
http://whereswalden.com/2010/04/06/more-changes-coming-to-spidermonkey-the-magical-__count__-property-of-objects-is-being-removed/

Comment: Now that Firefox 4 is out, this answer is now obsolete. `Object.__count__` is gone, and good riddance too.

Comment: I wouldn't say the answer is obsolete. It's still an interesting strategy to encapsulate a value in a function.

Comment: should be using the prototype object to extend

Answer (score 9):

From *[Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)*:

> Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)

You can either add it to all your objects:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "length", {
    enumerable: false,
    get: function() {
        return Object.keys(this).length;
    }
});
```

Or a single object:

```
var myObj = {};
Object.defineProperty(myObj, "length", {
    enumerable: false,
    get: function() {
        return Object.keys(this).length;
    }
});
```

Example:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.name  = "John Doe";
myObj.email = "leaked@example.com";
myObj.length; // Output: 2
```

Added that way, it won't be displayed in *for..in* loops:

```
for(var i in myObj) {
    console.log(i + ": " + myObj[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
name: John Doe
email: leaked@example.com
```

Note: it does not work in browsers before [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9).

Comment: If you’re going to extend built-in prototypes or polyfill a property (i.e. monkey-patch), please do it correctly: for forward compatibility, check if the property exists first, then make the property non-enumerable so that the own keys of constructed objects aren’t polluted. For methods use _actual_ [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions). My recommendation: follow [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491279/4642212) which demonstrate how to add a method that behaves as closely as possible like built-in methods.

Answer (score 8):

For those who have Underscore.js included in their project you can do:

```js
_({a:'', b:''}).size() // => 2
```

or functional style:

```js
_.size({a:'', b:''}) // => 2
```

Comment: The question was not about other methods, but the fastest method. You propose using library, which already by itself fails in performance.

Answer (score 6):

How I've solved this problem is to build my own implementation of a basic list which keeps a record of how many items are stored in the object. It’s very simple. Something like this:

```
function BasicList()
{
   var items = {};
   this.count = 0;

   this.add = function(index, item)
   {
      items[index] = item;
      this.count++;
   }

   this.remove = function (index)
   {
      delete items[index];
      this.count--;
   }

   this.get = function(index)
   {
      if (undefined === index)
        return items;
      else
        return items[index];
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. This does eliminate the overhead of an aggregate counting function, but at the cost of a function call every time you add or remove an element, which unfortunately may be worse. I'd personnaly use such a list implementation for the data encapsulation and custom methods it can provide compared to a plain array, but not when I just need fast item counting.

Comment: I like your answer, but I also am a lemming and clicked upvote. This presents an interesting dilemma. You're not accounting for some behavior in your instructions, such as my situation where I've already upvoted your answer, but then I am instructed to "click upvote" and cannot. The instruction fails silently but I gather from your content here on SO that failing silently is not something you like your code doing. Just a heads up.

Comment: I really like this answer, nice data structure. And if there was a performance impact with the function calls on add, there would be a far greater performance boost if having to iterate over an object. This should allow for the fastest loop patten `var i = basiclist.count` `while(i--){...}`

Comment: Shouldn't a basic list at least include basic checks? Like checking if `add` replaces an old item or if `remove` is called with a non-existing index. Also it's not possible to check if the list has a given index if `undefined` is a valid item value.

Comment: Shouldn't `get` have `if (undefined === index)`? As it is the test is reversed and will use an `undefined` index to access the array.

Comment: This is awful. If it's called a list it should behave like one. This is like some odd hybrid between a list and an object that doesn't do anything very well. I'd much rather just stick to basic data types.

Comment: @UltimateGobblement where does it not behave like a list?

Comment: A list should be ordered and iterable. Data is stored in an object so there's no guarantee on the ordering of elements. How do you find the length a list with holes in it? this.count? The highest index value? If you ever add two items at the same index the count goes into an error state.

Comment: @UltimateGobblement Fair enough. It is called 'basicList' though, its not a end all / be all. Its meant to be extended and customized.

Comment: This uses the set character of objects and if there are duplicate keys "count" wont be correct unless it takes existing keys into account.

Answer (score 4):

For those that have [Ext JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) 4 in their project, you can do:

```
Ext.Object.getSize(myobj);
```

The advantage of this is that it'll work on all Ext JS compatible browsers ([Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) - [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) included). However, I believe the running time is no better than O(n) though, as with other suggested solutions.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use:**

```
Object.keys(objectName).length;
```

and

```
Object.values(objectName).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Test

```js
const person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
};
console.log(
   Object.keys(person).length,
   Object.values(person).length,
   Object.entries(person).length
)
```

Comment: From looking at all the other answers, the important part of the question was tthe "efficiently" bit.

Answer (score -2):

If jQuery in previous answers does not work, then try

```
$(Object.Item).length
```

Comment: It seems that `Object.Item` does not exist

Comment: What  answer(s) in particular? Can you link to some or all of them?

Comment: OK, user *codejoecode* has left the building. Perhaps somebody else?

Answer (score -3):

I try to make it available to all objects like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,
                      "length",
                      {
                          get() {
                              if (!Object.keys) {
                                  Object.keys = function (obj) {
                                      var keys = [],k;
                                      for (k in obj) {
                                          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
                                              keys.push(k);
                                          }
                                      }
                                      return keys;
                                  };
                              }
                              return Object.keys(this).length;
                      },});

console.log({"Name":"Joe", "Age":26}.length) // Returns 2
```

Comment: Modifying objects you don't own is [a bad idea](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).