# Number of elements in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, collections, javascript-objects, element

Is there a way to get (from somewhere) the number of elements in a Javascript object?? (i.e. constant-time complexity).

I can't find a property or method that retrieves that information. So far I can only think of doing an iteration through the whole collection, but that's linear time.
It's strange there is no direct access to the size of the object, don't you think.

**EDIT:**
I'm talking about the `Object` object (not objects in general):

```
var obj = new Object ;
```

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip
Object.keys(obj).length

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Although JS implementations might keep track of such a value internally, there's no standard way to get it.

In the past, Mozilla's Javascript variant exposed the [non-standard `__count__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Properties_of_Object_instances), but it has been removed with version 1.8.5.

For cross-browser scripting you're stuck with explicitly iterating over the properties and checking `hasOwnProperty()`:

```
function countProperties(obj) {
    var count = 0;

    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

In case of ECMAScript 5 capable implementations, this can also be written as (Kudos to [Avi Flax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889658/48015))

```
function countProperties(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll also miss properties which aren't enumerable (eg an array's `length`).

If you're using a framework like jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, $whatever-the-newest-hype, check if they come with their own collections API, which might be a better solution to your problem than using native JS objects.

Comment: Goddamn it I always forget hasOwnProperty. Too much time in .NET land I tell you. +1

Comment: jQuery uses an object for its collections that it gets from queries, and it exposes that value with a length property.

Comment: Firefox4 `__count__` is gone :(

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a for in? I'm in the same type of bind but I'd like to make it pass JSLint if at all possible.

Comment: why do we need `hasOwnProperty()` ?

Comment: It's 2022. This answer is pretty outdated now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428315/1852005 is much clearer. No browser today *doesn't* support ES6, let alone ES5. The `countProperties` is redundant.

Answer (score 153):

To do this in any ES5-compatible environment

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

(Browser support from [here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_keys))
(Doc on Object.keys [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), includes method you can add to non-ECMA5 browsers)

Comment: This is not the right question to put this answer on. With that you are taking all the keys of the object, putting them in a newly created array and then retrieving the length property from that new array.

Comment: It may not be the most programmatically efficient, but it is the most developer efficient.

Comment: I agree, it´s definately the fastest (short, quickly done) way to do this. Works well with nested objects too, if you are only interested in the sub-object´s own keys, `Object.keys(obj.nested_obj).length`.

Answer (score 10):

*if* you are already using jQuery in your build just do this:

```
$(yourObject).length
```

It works nicely for me on objects, and I already had jQuery as a dependancy.

Comment: Strange... this doesn't work for me.  I always get 1.  ZelkiN's answer works for me.

Comment: This code always return 1. Just 1 object. It is not counting elements in it

Comment: Did one of the up voters check the code? It doesn't work and returns always 1 - regardless what `yourObject` contains.

Answer (score 7):

```
function count(){
    var c= 0;
    for(var p in this) if(this.hasOwnProperty(p))++c;
    return c;
}

var O={a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

count.call(O);
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this reliably, unless you switch to an array.  Which honestly, *doesn't* seem strange - it's seems pretty straight forward to me that arrays are countable, and objects aren't.

Probably the closest you'll get is something like this

```
// Monkey patching on purpose to make a point
Object.prototype.length = function()
{
  var i = 0;
  for ( var p in this ) i++;
  return i;
}

alert( {foo:"bar", bar: "baz"}.length() ); // alerts 3
```

But this creates problems, or at least questions.  All user-created properties are counted, including the _length function itself!  And while in this simple example you could avoid it by just using a normal function, that doesn't mean you can stop other scripts from doing this.  so what do you do?  Ignore function properties?

```
Object.prototype.length = function()
{
  var i = 0;
  for ( var p in this )
  {
      if ( 'function' == typeof this[p] ) continue;
      i++;
  }
  return i;
}

alert( {foo:"bar", bar: "baz"}.length() ); // alerts 2
```

In the end, I think you should probably ditch the idea of making your objects countable and figure out another way to do whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: DANGER WILL ROBINSON! Do *NOT* proto against Object! Everything descends from Object, you'll cripple the client processing like this if you're doing any sizeable amount of JS work.

Comment: Uh... did you not read the part where I wrote in a comment "Monkey patching on purpose to make a point" - c'mon, I did that deliberately so that people wouldn't flip a bit about it. Besides, even though I don't advocate monkey patching, you misunderstand how the prototype chain works in Javascript if you think this would cause performance issues http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111585/1027823

Comment: So.. this is a do or a don't?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of number/length/dimensionality doesn't really make sense for an Object, and needing it suggests you really want an Array to me.

Edit: Pointed out to me that you want an O(1) for this. To the best of my knowledge no such way exists I'm afraid.

Comment: He proposed iterating himself, which this solution is. He needed an O(1) way to achieve this...

Comment: You're quite right. Really should read questions more thoroughly.

Comment: Actually, Objects are the closest thing to a Map there is in JS. Maps do have length.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery :

```
$(parent)[0].childElementCount
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.