# How do I know how many items an object literal contains?

Tags: javascript

For example, how do I know that the myObject object literal contains two items?

```
var myObject = {
  item1 : "blablabla",
  item2 : "blablabla
};
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345939/how-do-i-count-javascript-objects-attributes (see haim evgi's answer)

Comment: confusedly titled, though, oki

Answer (score 2):

[How do I count a JavaScript object's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345939/how-do-i-count-javascript-objects-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't override the prototypes of `myObject`,

```
var count = 0;
for (var k in myObject) ++ count;
return count;
```

Otherwise, see the answer haim's link.

Comment: What about properties inherited from the prototype chain?

Comment: The `for...in` statement iterates also properties that are up in the prototype chain, I would suggest you to check if the property exists *physically* in the object by `myObject.hasOwnProperty(k);` or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObject, k);` for the paranoid :)

Comment: I blame Douglas Crockford and JSLint.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 0
for (var i in o) ++n
alert(n)
```