# toBoolean method similar like toString

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to define a method on an `object` / `class` in JavaScript that acts like `toString` just for booleans? Example (es6):

```
class MyClass {
  toBoolean() {
    return this.foo === bar;
  }
}
```

so I can do something like this

```
const myClass = new MyClass();
if (myClass === true) baz();
```

sounds crazy to me, but I'm gonna ask nonetheless.

Comment: It doesnt even work like that for strings

Comment: Type coercion doesn't happen when using `===`

Comment: You can't do stuff like overloading the cast operator in C++. `toString` is just a bit special because many functions implicitly try calling `toString` on your objects, but `===` doesn't do anything like that. So there is no way to magically convert it to a boolean for comparison like this. One would still have to use `if(myClass.toBoolean() === true)`, and then it would make more sense to name the method by what it actually does, e.g. `if(myClass.isValid())` :P

Comment: use `return !!input_string` and add it to Objects prototype

Comment: @Thilo It's not very well researched, especially the stuff about when `toString` is used, etc., so I didn't think it was worth being an answer. But I'll make it an answer now...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081195/can-an-object-be-false

Comment: It really was a play of thought and a general question i had. I did not think through my example with `===` before I posted it.

Comment: Note that even `new Boolean(false)` is considered `true`.

Comment: Note that even if you used loose comparison (`==`), whenever you *compare* a Boolean to a different data type, you will end up comparing numbers, since the Boolean value is converted to a number first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the fact that it would be a can of worms as drewmoore pointed out, it's not possible to do it in JavaScript at all.

There is no feature to "hook type conversion" in a way like overloading the cast operator in C++.

The reason why `toString` appears to do something similar is just because many [functions implicitly try calling `toString` on your objects, and the JavaScript interpreter also does this when you try to concatenate something to a string using `+`](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/using-javascripts-tostring-method) but `===` doesn't do anything like that - in fact, the "selling point" of `===` is that it does *no type conversion*.

So there is no way to magically convert it to a boolean for comparison like this. One would still have to use `if(myClass.toBoolean() === true)`, and then it would make more sense to name the method by what it actually does, e.g. `if(myClass.isValid())` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, even if it were possible it'd be an awful idea:

```
const myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.foo = true;
if (myClass === true) baz();  //true
if (myClass) foobaz(); //true, as expected, since myClass === true

myClass.foo = false; 
if (myClass === true) baz(); // false
if (myClass) foobaz(); //true - wtf?
```

Answer (score -1):

This will solve your problem it will convert any type to Boolean.

```
function Fun (){

}
Fun.prototype.toBoolean = function(a) {
  return !!a;
}

var obj = new Fun("str");
obj.toBoolean("str");
obj.toBoolean(1);
obj.toBoolean({});
obj.toBoolean(0);
```

Comment: @Thilo removed it.