# What `if ([ ])` turns out to be,it seems not falsy

Tags: javascript

I got an empty array from previously code running,and I wanted to check whether it was empty within an if statement,I used

```
if (emptyArr) {
  //do something here. 
}
```

at first,received some weird results,now I know that I should use `if (emptyArr.length === 0 ) {}` instead,but only for curiosity,what the code block above results in?

Comment: Have you tried running `var foo = []; if (foo) { console.out("bar"); } else { console.out("baz"); }`?

Comment: `!![]` → `true` – In other words, an empty array is still *truthy*.

Comment: If it is different than `0`, `undefined`, `false`, `null` (i.e. falsy values), then it is the same as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty array is still an object, and an object reference is always `true` in an `if` predicate like that. Thus

```
if ([]) alert("hello world");
```

will always trigger the alert.

Comment: Solution: use `length`.

Comment: @Tushar yes, as the OP says.

Answer (score -1):

```
typeof []
"object"
```

So as `if({})` turns out to be true, `if([])` is true too.

Here is question about [Why object is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081195/can-an-object-be-false)