# How can you cause a javascript Object to be treated as falsy?

Tags: javascript, null, proxy-classes, coalescing

The use case I'm considering is creating a hopelessly egocentric `Null` for coalescing.

This code works but requires an explicit check against the `Null` in question:

```js
const Null = new Proxy({}, {get: () => Null});

let data = Null;

console.log(data.a.b.c.d !== Null ? "Has value" : "Is Null");
```

I'd like to be able to leave out the explicit check and simply do

```
console.log(data.a.b.c.d ? "Has value" : "Is Null");
```

but that doesn't work because my `Null` is an object, and as such is treated as truthy.

The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) seems to indicate that this isn't possible, but javascript is such a weird ecosystem that I'm hoping someone will be able to come up with a possible solution.

(Also please don't debate the merits of this kind of `Null`, I know it's a potentially contentious issue and I'm purely interested in if it CAN be done, not whether it SHOULD be done.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an Object be false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081195/can-an-object-be-false)

Comment: Use a utility function that returns what you want

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. An object reference is never "falsy". You can add `valueOf()` and `toString()` methods that return false values when they're invoked, but if all that's tested is a reference that won't do any good.

Comment: An immediate counter-example is `document.all instanceof Object`, with `!!document.all === false` but that does seem to be a lone exception that is impossible to emulate. 

I wasn't really after a < 5 minute "No" as an answer, so I'm going to leave the question open until either someone comes along with a novel method, or the language evolves to a point where it does become possible to do this.

Comment: @david what? `document.all` is archaic, and in any browser in this day and age the value will be `undefined`. Maybe IE preserves it, even in Edge, but then it *won't* be `undefined`. I'm not sure I see what you're on about here. In any case, an actual object reference will definitely **never** be false.

Comment: @david also `document.all instanceof Object` returns `true` in Firefox, and `!!document.all == false` returns `false`, which makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yeah it's archaic, but it's there. Most browsers will preserve it because backwards compatibility is a massive thing in web development.

Comment: Interesting, my version of firefox has `!!document.all === false` returning `true`. What version are you checking on? Mine is `52.0a2 (2016-12-06) (64-bit)`

Comment: Firefox 50.1.0 returns `true` for `!!document.all === false` because it **is** true. `document.all` is `undefined` in modern Firefox.

Comment: I thought you said `document.all instanceof Object` returned `true` in your browser? `undefined instanceof Object` would return `false`.

Comment: No, in Firefox v50 `document.all` is `undefined`, and `undefined` is not an instance of `Object`.

Comment: The fact that `document.all instanceof Object` returns `true` probably has something to do with what happens to `undefined` on the left side of `instanceof`. It's `undefined` because Firefox doesn't implement it. If it ends up being an instance of 'Object` it's because something turns it into `null` I bet.