# How to deal with different JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I would like to deal with differnet JSON-Formats.

In my first example I'am using this answering-format from PHP:

```
{
    "errors": [ "username", "password" ]
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.sample.com/js/l.php",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
        if (jsonResponse['errors']) {
            var t = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse['errors'].length; i++) {    
                //works well for: {"errors":["username","password"]} ';
                t = t + jsonResponse['errors'][i] + "  ";
            }
            console.log(t);
        }
    }
});
```

The result of console is: username  password

If I change the json-response to

```
{
    "errors": { 
        "username": ["credentials"],
        "password": ["credentials"]
    }
}
```

I do not know how do deal with this.

The function do not work because the `jsonResponse['errors'].length` is empty.

I would like to loop to username password with their values.

Comment: This is an array. Instead of `errors.username` you use `errors.username[0]` (for the first value). You can loop through unknown keys by using `for (var key in obj) { console.log(obj[key]); }`.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `errors` is an array, containing two values.

```
Object: {array: [element1, element2]}
```

In your second example, `errors` is an object, and objects don't have a `length` property.

```
Object: {Object: {array: [element], array[element]}}
```

To count the number of elements in an object, you have to iterate over the elements and count them. See the question below to see how:

[How do I count a JavaScript object's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345939/how-do-i-count-a-javascript-objects-attributes)

Comment: If I do: for (var k in jsonErrors) {t = t +  jsonErrors[k] +"  ";} console.log(t); I will get object object not the values.