# Get the object length in angularjs is undefined

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the object length ?

In console my object looks like this:

```
Object {
 2: true,
 3: true,
 4: true
}
```

`.length` will give me **undefined**. I just want to get the `results = 3` for this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get object length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
var keys = Object.keys(objInstance);
var len = keys.length;
```

Where len is your "length."

There may be circumstances I haven't thought of where this doesn't work, but it should do what you need, given your example.

Comment: Thanks. This is strange, but the key moment here is that you need to get keys first and assign it to a variable, only then, you can get the length.
Object.keys(objInstance).length will not work

Comment: This appears to be a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345939/how-do-i-count-a-javascript-objects-attributes ... not sure why monstro says Object.keys(objInstance).length won't work, though I do see comments in that link I provided that indicate it may not work with older (IE8 and below) browsers. Try it with a modern browser and you may be surprised at the results.

Answer (score 11):

Combining some of these answers into

```
app.filter('numkeys', function() {
  return function(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).length;
  }
});
```

seems to work

```
<div ng-show="(furry.animals | numkeys) > 10">lots of furry animals</div>
```

Comment: Just perfect ;)

Answer (score 6):

You could also use a filter

**Edit:**

```
app.filter('objLength', function() { 
 return function(object) { 
  return Object.keys(object).length; 
 } 
});
```

**Old Answer:**

```
app.filter('objLength', function() {
 return function(object) {
  var count = 0;

  for(var i in object){
   count++;
  }
  return count;
 }
});
```

And then use it maybe like this

```
<div ng-hide="(navigations._source.languages | objLength) == 1"> content</div>
```

Comment: A better way to do this:

`app.filter('objLength', function() {
    return function(object) {
        return Object.keys(object).length;
    }
});`

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to repeat that Object.keys(obj) everywhere you want to get the length, as the code might get pretty messy. Therefore just put it in some personal project snippet library to be available across the site:

```
Object.prototype.length = function(){
    return Object.keys(this).length
}
```

and than when you need to know object 's length you can run

```
exampleObject.length()
```

there's one problem with above, if you create an object that would have a "length" key, you will break the "prototype" function:

```
exampleObject : { length: 100, width: 150 }
```

but you can use your own synonym for length, like "l()" instead of "length()"

Comment: It is [dangerous to directly extend Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) as all JavaScript objects use this prototype chain as part of JS core functionality and may create other problems.

Answer (score 4):

it can be get by below code simply

`var itemsLength = Object.keys(your object).length;`

Comment: This works in console, but not in angular app, see the answer above.

Comment: check this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: you can get object length in javascript or javascript based libs in your apps

Answer (score 2):

Short variant `Object.keys($scope.someobject).length`

Answer (score 0):

We can also add a small validation if we are retrieving data from API.

```
app.filter('objLength', function() { 
 return function(object) { 
  return object ? Object.keys(object).length : "";
 } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Even I don't understand why in Angular markup not able to get the value of Objects via 'Object.keys'. But here there's some easy [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-length?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Check it out.