# Angularjs can't get array length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the array length, when i console log

```
console.log($scope.community)
```

I do get a return, but when i try doing the method i found online , like [Get the object length in angularjs is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108089/get-the-object-length-in-angularjs-is-undefined)

```
   var array = Object.keys($scope.community);
   var len = array.length;
   console.log(len)
```

I am returned with 0 and no error

[image]

Array call :

```
    var all = displayAll.callAll()
        .then(function(response) {
           $scope.all = response;
           for (var i=0; i< $scope.all.length; i++) {

                if ($scope.all[i].CATEGORY == 'Community')
                {
                    $scope.community.push($scope.all[i]);

                }
```

Comment: please show the result of your console.log($scope.community)

Comment: updated @holydragon

Comment: have you tried console.log($scope.community.length)?

Comment: Ya, it returns me 0 as well

Comment: Please show the whole code that includes how you get your data into $scope.community and how you console.log() it. It may be caused by asynchronous request.

Comment: Hmm yeah, i forgot about that. Think it might be asynchronous as I am fetching a http call from my factory

Comment: Now that if you call console.log($scope.community.length) after the for loop, you should get the length.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Any way to access it outside? I need to pass the length somewhere

Comment: You have to access the length after the request is done, so you will have the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = $scope.community.length;
console.log(len);
```

should return the length of the community.
Plus this method can also be used in Native JS, even without using AngularJS.

Comment: Returned 0 in console