# Difference between create array using new Array() and new Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I see the example that creates an array using

```
var array = new Array(5);
```

but also I see something like this

```
arrayObj[0] = "index zero";
arrayObj[10] = "index ten";
```

I think the above code creates an object with two field name 0 and 10 like below? Is that correct?

```
arrayobj {
0: "index zero"
10: "index ten"
}
```

any different in this two way to create array using new Array() and new Object ?

Comment: Just test it: `var arrayObj = []; arrayObj[0] = "index zero"; arrayObj[10] = "index ten"; console.log(arrayObj)` / `var arrayObj = {}; arrayObj[0] = "index zero"; arrayObj[10] = "index ten"; console.log(arrayObj)`

Comment: `new Array(5);` - this will create a sparse array with only `length` property and no array elements.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` and `Object` are different from eachother. Technically what you are doing makes the data structure and utility for time being as same but you miss on prototype functions and cannot use it crossside.

E.g `Array.forEach()` will loop on an array but it will not loop on an object whose key/value pair are equivalent to that of index/item of an array

```js
var array = new Array(5).fill('index');

arrayObj = {};
arrayObj[0] = "index zero";
arrayObj[10] = "index ten";
try {
  console.log(array.length);
  array.forEach(i => console.log(i));
  
  

  console.log(arrayObj.length);
  arrayObj.forEach(i => console.log(i));
  } catch (e) { console.error(e); }
  
  //looping over Object
  
  Object.keys(arrayObj).forEach((item)=>{ 
     console.log(arrayObj[item]);
  });
```

Comment: beside " for (field in arrayobj)"  , Can I use for (var i=0; i<arrayobj.length; i++) to loop on the arrayobj? Because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345939/how-do-i-count-a-javascript-objects-attributes. mention some way to get the size of the object

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(arrayObj).length` to get the length however using `arrayObj.length` directly will return `undefined`

Comment: therefore ,  for (var i=0; i<Object.keys(arrayObj).length ;i++) can loop on the arrayobj ?

Comment: @SamLi yes, kindly check the updated snippet on how to loop over an object

Comment: @SamLi also kindly accept the answer it if addresses your issue, thanks