# Length of an object filled with objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an object filled with objects and I want to know how many items are in it. How can I do this with JS? Also running jQuery in the page.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function countProperties(obj) {
    var count = 0;

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

See also: [Number of elements in a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956719/number-of-elements-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. And by the way, it would be appreciated if you accepted my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just did, sorry you were too fast and I had to wait out the 5 min clock :)

Answer (score 0):

For ECMAScript 5-compatible agents, for example Chrome, try this:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
console.log('Your object has ' + Object.keys(obj).length + ' elements in it');

// Your object has 3 elements in it
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip).

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

"object filled with objects" is more commonly known as an array. Anyway:

```
yourObject.length
```

Comment: An array is also an object. `b = new Array(); typeof b` displays
`"object"`

Comment: See my answer below; by "array" I mean the "Array()" object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array And also, length is a property of only the Array object, not the Object object

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree.  yes, an array is an object.  no, an object is not an array. `var x = {a:1}; console.log(x.length);  // undefined`