# MongoDB: How do I find number of items in embedded document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My schema looks like

```
name:
value:
p_vars: {
    name1: {},
    name2: {},
}
```

I want to count how many items are there in `p_vars`.

Thinking that interpretor is `JavaScript`, I tried

```
db.collection.findOne().p_vars.length
```

But nothing returns

**Answer should be**

Considering above, answer should be 2(two items `name1` and `name2`)

Comment: `p_vars` is an object. Objects don't have lengths in javascript. Why exactly did you expect this to work?

Comment: I want to know how many items are in p_vars, like count of `name1` + `name2` + ....

Comment: As this is a javascript object, maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956719/number-of-elements-in-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution here is to change your schema to use an array of p_vars, which it sounds like you want anyway.  If instead the schema was:

```js
name:
value:
p_vars: [
    name1: {},
    name2: {},
]
```

Then the `db.collection.findOne().p_vars.length` command would return 2 as you expect.

With the original schema, the only option I think you have is to write a JS function to iterate and count the elements manually.