# Simulating map/set in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json object, say `box = {};` to which I will keep adding key-values like `box['somename'] = somevalue`. There may be repetitions of `somename` and I want the last instance's value to win. All this is fine.

Now I need to operate on it, as if it were an array. Basically, now that I have a set of unique keys, I want one main operation `box.length` to see how many unique elements there are. Is there an elegant constant time way of doing it without iterating through all properties of this object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: yes, looks like that, but the answers here are much better, don't you think :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var box = { 
  length: 0,
  add: function(k, v) {
    if (typeof this[k] === 'undefined')
      this.length++;
    this[k] = v;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also check whether `k != "length"` before you make the assignment.

Comment: @Jan: True, the add method should probably raise an error if k is "length" or any other special property of box.

Comment: What if you reomve a key/value pair (`delete box[somekey]`)?

Comment: @Kooilnc: `delete: function(k) { if (typeof this[k] !== 'undefined') this.length--; delete this[k]; }`

Comment: @Eric Mickelsen: and what if you don't use `add` (`box.somenewkey = 'directset'`)?

Comment: @Kooilnc: In that case, you're SOL no matter what.  There is no way in Javascript to prevent such a thing.  The presumption here is that you will use the provided functions consistently.

Answer (score 4):

Increment a counter every time you add a new element to `box`.

```
function Box() {
    var length = 0;
    var items = {};
    this.add = function(k, v) {
        if (!(k in items))
            length++; // don't count twice
        items[k] = v;
    }
    this.get = function(k) {
        return items[k];
    }
    this.delete = function(k) {
        if (k in items)
            length--; 
        delete items[k];
    }
    this.__defineGetter__("length", function() { 
        return length; 
    });
}
```

This version correctly handles adding and removing elements with any name and provides read-only access to the `length` property. Usage:

```
var box = new Box();
box.add("a", 1);
box.add("a", 2); // overwrite
box.add("b", "whatever");
box.add(null, 3);
box.add(undefined, 3);
box.add(undefined, 42);
box.add("", 41);
console.log(box.length); // 5
console.log(box.get(undefined)); // 42 
console.log(box.get(null)); // 3 
console.log(box.get("")); // 41
box.delete(undefined); 
box.delete(undefined); 
box.delete(undefined); 
box.delete(undefined); 
box.delete(undefined); 
box.delete(undefined); 
box.delete(22); // never was defined
console.log(box.length); // 4
console.log(box.get(undefined)); // undefined 
box.add("length", "33") 
box.add("items", "jfhsdjkfh"); 
box.add("length", 77);
console.log(box.length); // 6
```

Comment: @Eric - Fixed, but I like your solution better anyway. Much more JavaScripty.

Comment: Probably nit-picking, but yours is a more robust approach, since the value itself can be `undefined`. Calling `box.addItem("a", undefined)`  multiple times will not increment the `length`. +1