# Removing empty object keys in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I'm trying to create an array that sort of summarises another array. I've already received some really good ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796640/convert-multi-dimensional-array-into-single-array-javascript), all of them are working, but all of them generate another obstacle that I, again, can't seem to solve.

Based on @kooiinc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32796854/4593394), my current code looks like this:

```
var grants = [
    { id: "p_1", location: "loc_1", type: "A", funds: "5000" },
    { id: "p_2", location: "loc_2", type: "B", funds: "2000" },
    { id: "p_3", location: "loc_3", type: "C", funds:  "500" },
    { id: "p_2", location: "_ibid", type: "D", funds: "1000" },
    { id: "p_2", location: "_ibid", type: "E", funds: "3000" }
];
var projects = [];
grants.map(
function (v) {
    if (!(v.id in this)) {
        this[v.id] = v;
        projects.push(v);
    } else {
        var current = this[v.id];
        current.type = [v.type].concat(current.type);
        current.funds = [v.funds].concat(current.funds);
    }
}, {});
```

... which gives the following desired result (`type` and `funds` joined into sub-arrays, the rest are pushed unchanged):

```
[
    { "id": "p_1", "location": "loc_1", "type": "A", "funds": "5000" },
    { "id": "p_2", "location": "loc_2", "type": ["E","D","B"], "funds": ["3000","1000","2000"] },
    { "id": "p_3", "location": "loc_3", "type": "C", "funds": "500" }
]
```

However, if some of the objects have some  undefined key values, the result will have nulls in the arrays. For example like this (look at the `type` array):

```
[
    { "id": "p_1", "location": "loc_1", "type": "A", "funds": "5000" },
    { "id": "p_2", "location": "loc_2", "type": ["E",null,null], "funds": ["3000","1000","2000"] },
    { "id": "p_3", "location": "loc_3", "type": "C", "funds": "500" }
]
```

*(Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/casbaup3/) with the same thing.)*

I've tried to find a quick way of removing these afterwards (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722873/sorting-and-removing-keys-with-null-values) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)) but for some reason none of the usual methods (of recursively removing all keys that are undefined/null) seem to work, regardless of where I put them in my code. They don't give errors, they just won't remove anything.

Is it perhaps possible to already exclude the undefined keys in the mapping somehow?

**Update:** So some of the object keys won't have *any* values, just `[null,null,null]` whilst others will have a few but not all like `["E",null,null]`. The idea is to remove all the null items and if there's nothing left then remove the object key as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
grants.map(
 function (v) {
    if (!(v.id in this)) {
        // => initialize if empty
        v.type = v.type || [];
        v.funds = v.funds || [];
        this[v.id] = v;
        projects.push(v);
    } else {
        var current = this[v.id];
        current.type = v.type ? [v.type].concat(current.type) : current.type;
        current.funds = v.funds ? [v.funds].concat(current.funds) : current.funds;
    }
 }, {});
```

Now empty values will not show up in the result.

Comment: Yep, I thought of this too but this doesn't seem to remove all the nulls, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/eebgasw6/1/

Comment: I see, there is a pretty simple solution. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can test the occurrence of both `type` and `funds` properties and only if exist, then insert or update the element.

```
a.type && a.funds && ...
```

```js
var grants = [
        { id: "p_1", location: "loc_1", type: "A", funds: "5000" },
        { id: "p_2", location: "loc_2", funds: "2000" },
        { id: "p_3", location: "loc_3", type: "C", funds: "500" },
        { id: "p_2", location: "_ibid", funds: "1000" },
        { id: "p_2", location: "_ibid", type: "E", funds: "3000" }
    ],
    project = [];

grants.forEach(function (a) {
    a.type && a.funds && !project.some(function (b, i) {
        if (a.id === b.id) {
            project[i].type.push(a.type);
            project[i].funds.push(a.funds);
            return true;
        }
    }) && project.push({ id: a.id, location: a.location, type: [a.type], funds: [a.funds] });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(project, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The problem with this would be that I lose the ability to join the ones I want to join (`type` and `funds` in the example).