# Finding the number of keys in an object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)

```
var values = [{
    'SPO2': 222.00000,
    'VitalGroupID': 1152,
    'Temperature': 36.6666666666667,
    'DateTimeTaken': '/Date(1301494335000-0400)/',
    'UserID': 1,
    'Height': 182.88,
    'UserName': null,
    'BloodPressureDiastolic': 80,
    'Weight': 100909.090909091,
    'TemperatureMethod': 'Oral',
    'Resprate': null,
    'HeartRate': 111,
    'BloodPressurePosition': 'Standing',
    'VitalSite': 'Popliteal',
    'VitalID': 1135,
    'Laterality': 'Right',
    'HeartRateRegularity': 'Regular',
    'HeadCircumference': '',
    'BloodPressureSystolic': 120,
    'CuffSize': 'XL'
}];

for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
        alert(values.length) // gives me 2.
```

How can find how many keys my object has?

Comment: Two things: 1) Why are you looping through `values.length` yet also alerting `values.length`? 2) I swear `values.length` is not going to give you 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array

Comment: Further to @BoltClock's comment, [`alert(values.length);` gives: `1`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UvthC/). And, incidentally, from my own training, the saturated partial arterial pressure of oxygen (`SPO2`), should be a percentage value of up to `100` (percent, obviously). Where's the `222.00000` coming from? I'm not intending to be confrontational, but I **am** curious... =)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
var value = {
    'SPO2': 222.00000,
    'VitalGroupID': 1152,
    'Temperature': 36.6666666666667,
    'DateTimeTaken': '/Date(1301494335000-0400)/',
    'UserID': 1,
    'Height': 182.88,
    'UserName': null,
    'BloodPressureDiastolic': 80,
    'Weight': 100909.090909091,
    'TemperatureMethod': 'Oral',
    'Resprate': null,
    'HeartRate': 111,
    'BloodPressurePosition': 'Standing',
    'VitalSite': 'Popliteal',
    'VitalID': 1135,
    'Laterality': 'Right',
    'HeartRateRegularity': 'Regular',
    'HeadCircumference': '',
    'BloodPressureSystolic': 120,
    'CuffSize': 'XL'
};

alert(Object.keys(value).length);
```

Comment: How can i find the total number of keys if the Object is inside an array

Answer (score 7):

try

```
Object.keys(values).length
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

for compatiblity

```
if(!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o){
 if (o !== Object(o))
      throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
 var ret=[],p;
 for(p in o) if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) ret.push(p);
 return ret;
}
```

or use:

```
function numKeys(o){
var i=0;
for(p in o) if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)){ i++};
return i;
}
```

Comment: which you should attribute to its source...

Answer (score 5):

```
function numKeys(o) {
   var res = 0;
   for (var k in o) {
       if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) res++;
   }
   return res;
}
```

or, in newer browsers:

```
function numKeys(o) {
   return Object.keys(o).length;
}
```

In your example, `values` is an array with one element, so you'd call `numKeys(values[0])` to find out.

Comment: #2 should be `Object.keys(o).length`

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate and just count:

```
var i = 0;
for(var key in values[0]) if(values[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) i++;
// now i is amount
```

Comment: This will include properties defined by the object prototype

Comment: @phihag: You're correct but you should not extend `Object.prototype` anyway.

Comment: @pimvdb indeed you shouldn't, but you should program defensively in case one of the libraries you're using has.