# How can i find the total number of keys if the Object is inside an array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)

```
var array = [{key:value,key:value}]
```

How can i find the total number of keys if it's an array of Object. When i do check the length of the array, it gives me one.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Its an array of objects... not a plain object..

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: His previous question is a dupe of that, this one asks something a little different. Not sure if it should've been a separate question, but I guess he didn't get responses from the earlier post.

Comment: It is right - there is one object in the array. The question needs some polishing... Are you trying to get the total number of keys from the object in the array? Or something else?

Comment: @John Cooper, well then apply the technique in the dupe to `array[0]` which is a single object.

Comment: @Nicolae Albu: Yes i am trying to get the total number of keys from the object in an array

Comment: This is duplicate of what Darin found, no doubt there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the number of unique properties of `Object`s in an `Array`, this should do it...

```
var uniqueProperties = [];

for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
   for (var prop in arr[i]) {
       if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) 
           && uniqueProperties.indexOf(prop) === -1
          ) {
          uniqueProperties.push(prop);
       }
   } 
}

var uniquePropertiesLength = uniqueProperties.length;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/exdYG/).

Note that an `Array`'s [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) doesn't have the best browser support. You can always [augment the `Array` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) (though for safety I'd make it part of a `util` object or similar).

Comment: What does this mean uniqueProperties.indexOf(propertyName) === -1

Comment: @JohnCooper: It checks to see if the property name already exists in the `uniqueProperties` `Array`. Be sure to check the footnote about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the array will only have one object, `array[0]` represents the object.

If there's more than one object, you'll need to decide what exactly you want to count.