# Loop through JSON in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have codes in EJS below,

```
<script>
    var row =<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>
    console.log(row);
</script>
<% for(var i=0; i<JSON.stringify(data).length; i++) {%>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <%= JSON.stringify(data)[i].id%>
     </td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```

output of row is correct, an array of 3 objects, each with properties id, name etc.. I can manipulate the row to popuate the table in JS. However, I am wonderring whether there is a way to allow it be done in the above manner?

When I run the code above, JSON.stringify(data).length is not 3, but rather the length of the whole string.

Another questions is when I try to add

<% alert('t'); %> or <% window.alert('t'); %>, it gives me 'not defined' error...

Helps appreciated.

Regards
Hammer

Comment: Inside your for loop you can just reference `data` since it is being manipulated on the server (i.e. you want to manipulate it as a real object, not as a string). Regarding your second question, `alert` and `window` are browser-specific and aren't n node.

Comment: Thanks Barry. is it possible in EJS, I defined a function or var in <script> and referenced in <% %>?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` returns a `String`. So, for example:

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, name: "bob" },
    { id: 2, name: "john" },
    { id: 3, name: "jake" },
];

JSON.stringify(data)
```

will return the equivalent of:

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"bob\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"john\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"jake\"}]"
```

as a `String` value.

So when you have

```
<% for(var i=0; i<JSON.stringify(data).length; i++) {%>
```

what that ends up looking like is:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"bob\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"john\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"jake\"}]".length; i++) {%>
```

which is probably *not* what you want. What you probably *do* want is something like this:

```
<table>
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= data[i].id %></td>
     <td><%= data[i].name %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

This will output the following table (using the example `data` from above):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>bob</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>john</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>jake</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello ! This is correct. but how to do same thing with _html_ rendered page  not with _ejs_??

Comment: @SPnL That's not possible. With EJS you can use JS code before the render thing happens.

Answer (score 4):

in my case, `datas` is an objects of Array for more information please [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forof.asp)

```
<% for(let [index,data] of datas.entries() || []){  %>
 Index : <%=index%>
 Data : <%=data%>
<%} %>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I have edit the code please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify(data).length return string length not Object length, you can use Object.keys.

```
<% for(var i=0; i < Object.keys(data).length ; i++) {%>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379528/3224296

Answer (score 0):

My way of creating dynamic options on a select is :

```
<optgroup label="Select Table">
    <% for(var i=0; i<doctors.length; i++) {%>
        <% fullname = doctors[i].surname + doctors[i].name %>
        <option name="doctor" value=" <%= fullname%> "><%= fullname%></option>
    <% } %>
</optgroup>
```

I have sent the data from the response and i just iterate it with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something of this sort you may try. Not necessary you need to use Dbjson, just refer for syntax

```
const codifyOptions = codifier.DatabaseCodifyOptions
const databaseOptions = databasifier.SqlServerDatabaseOptions
const dbJson = databasifier.getDatabaseJson(project, codifyOptions, databaseOptions)

dbJson.tables.forEach(table => {

  const tableName = codifier.codifyText(
        table.domain ? table.domain.concat("_", table.name) : table.name,
        codifyOptions 
  
  )
```