# How do I loop through in ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

```
 [{ Url: 'http://example.com', Shortname: 'shortname', Name: 'nameaaa' }, { Url: 'fsadfsad', Shortname: 'aaa', Name: 'fasfsad' } ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through JSON in EJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952044/loop-through-json-in-ejs)

Comment: since its in an array object, couldnt find any. Thanks.

Comment: nevermind got mine working, its a issue with the schema defining , should be under subschema

Comment: <% model.navigation.forEach(function(s){ %>

    <%= s.Url %>

<% }); %>

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You loop in ejs always the same way as you loop in regular javascript. So, for example if

```
 data = [{ Url: 'http://example.com', Shortname: 'shortname', Name: 'nameaaa' }, { Url: 'fsadfsad', Shortname: 'aaa', Name: 'fasfsad' } ]
```

You could do something like this to loop through the data array.

```
<% for (var key in data) { %>
    <h3><%= data[key].Url %></h3>
    <h3><%= data[key].Shortname %></h3>
    <h3><%= data[key].Name %></h3>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

its was a issue with my schema defining.

```
"navigation": {
            "type": "List",
            "title": "Navigation",
            "itemType": "Object",
            "subSchema": {
                "Name": {
                    "type": "Text",
                    "title": "Name"
                },
                "Shortname": {
                    "type": "Text",
                    "title": "Shortname"
                },
                "Url": {
                    "type": "Text",
                    "title": "URL"
                }
            }
        },            
<% model.navigation.forEach(function(s){ %>

<%= s.Url %>
<% }); %>
```

Thanks.