# Node.js returns [object Object] from MySQL query inside Javascript code

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, ejs

I am running a server on node.js. When I look at the result inside Google Chrome by typing localhost:3030 it returns the value `[object Object]`.

this is the app.js code here:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var app = express();
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'abcdefg',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'test'
    });

    app.get("/", function(req,res){
      var q = "select * from showdata";
      connection.query(q, function(err, results){
        if(err) throw err;
        var products = results;
        res.render("home", {data: products});
      });
    });

    app.listen(3030, function(){
      console.log("server running on 3030");
    })
```

and this is the .ejs file:

```
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p> <strong><%=data%></strong></p>
```

No errors show up. It just says `[object Object]`, whereas it should return all values from the query.

Comment: your results are an array of items. You need to loop over them

Comment: where would I write the loop specifically ?

Comment: probably right before the `res.render('home', ...)`

Comment: Unfortunately duplicates the same result

Comment: pmkro spot on that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<% data.forEach(function(item) { %>

    <p> <strong><%= item %></strong></p>

<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

pmkro helped with linking the correct website:
[Loop through JSON in EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952044/loop-through-json-in-ejs)
This is the code I used:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<% data.forEach(function(item) { %>

    <p> <strong><%= item %></strong></p>

<% }); %>
```