# How to get the count of data returned through $.get method

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
 $.get('getstatsAccepted' + tickerid, {tickerid: tickerid}, function(data) {
                     alert(data.length);
                }, 'json');
```

I want to alert the count of rows returned through this method. How to do this?

Comment: Can you post what the `data` is?

Comment: The data is simply a list or names with about 10-15 names

Comment: You want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'data' represent a values which you return from server. if you need to get count of  list or names, you have to return it as a JSON array.

You can use something like this. (I did not test this). See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6756305/2345900

```
$.get('getstatsAccepted' + tickerid, {tickerid: tickerid}, function(data) {

var key, count = 0;
for(key in data.names) {
  if(data.names.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    count++;
  }
}
    alert(count);
});
```