# JavaScript Ajax data is array but length is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Json result:

(Taken from the console)

```
data
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 7: Object}
```

if i in the console do `data[0]` i get the following result:

```
Object {id: 125, Module_id: 2, academy_id: 7, Team_id: 5, end: "2014-08-12 00:00:00"…}
```

However when i do `data.length` the value is `undefined` can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: data is not an array... it is an object so don't have length property

Comment: Change the JSON structure so it is an array of objects. You're trying to get the length of an object which is invalid.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6756305/1232526

Comment: Try this instead `Object.keys(data).length`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**

```
Object.keys(data).length;
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/p9qsn9sf/9/)

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

Comment: I think this is also working.  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).length

Answer (score 1):

You structured your json result as an `Object` **not** an `Array`. Do not mix those up! `data[0]` is the value of the first instance variable of the result object. If you want to structure your json object as an array before sending it to be parsed, then in your php file make sure you encode the object as an array

read.php

```
<?
    $data = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
    print json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: or he could just make `data` an array, as he's using it that way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as expected:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).length
```