# How can I count # of responses in jQuery $.ajax result?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to count the number of results in my $.ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        'async': true,
        'crossDomain': true,
        'url': 'XXX',
        'method': 'GET',
        'headers': {
            'key': 'XXX',
            'scope': 'XXX',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        },
        'processData': false,
        'data': {},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Default error
            log('error');

        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            log('success');
            log(data);
            var ArrayContent = data.length;
            log(ArrayContent)

        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        log('done');
    });
```

My jSon response is `Object {3858: Object, 4667: Object, 4668: Object, 4680: Object, 4710: Object}3858: Object4667: Object4668: Object4680: Object4710: Object__proto__: Object`

I have tried several solutions found on this site, but I cant get any of them to work.

Any suggestion towards a solution would be very much appreciated.

-C

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count? Number of keys or what? FYI, your data isn't an array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the number of own enumerable properties in the object using this code:

```
Object.keys(response).length;
```

Comment: Ya but then a comment would be better/more useful than a downvote ;)

Comment: Comments needs to be typed...but downvote is easy..just a click...:-P

Comment: That was me, then I got distracted mid comment... I dislike the content of your answer. The code may be fine, but (as far as I'm concerned) any variation of "Try this" doesn't make for a good answer. "Try this" is a suggestion or request, neither of which gives any confidence to the reader that you're actually sure about the information you're providing. Stick to statements such as "You can find the number of keys in the object using this code:" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the length of the json returned to your ajax function

`var count = Object.keys(data).length;`

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756104/get-size-of-json-object

Answer (score -1):

```
var json = JSON.parse(result);
var lengthofObject = json.length; // this is the number of elements in your response
```

Comment: The response is an *Object*, not an *Array*.