# Efficiently counting the number of keys / properties of an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, object, node.js, key

This question is almost identical to [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip).

I want to know one extra piece of information: what is a "**constant-time**" way of determining the number of keys in an Object?  I am mostly concerned with doing this in Node.JS, as most Objects on the browser aren't too large to be of great concern.

**EDIT:**
It appears that `Object.keys(obj).length` returns in linear time O(n) in Google Chrome and in Node.JS (i.e. dependent on the number of keys in `obj`). Is there a better O(1) method?

I did some testing in Node.JS (source is below)

```
var tests = [10e3, 10e4, 10e5, 10e6]
for(j in tests) {
    var obj = {};
    for(i = 0; i < tests[j]; i++)
        obj[i] = i;
    console.time('test' + tests[j]);
    Object.keys(obj).length;
    console.timeEnd('test' + tests[j]);
}
```

For n = 10e3, 10e4, 10e5, 10e6... results are:

```
test10000: 5ms
test100000: 20ms
test1000000: 371ms
test10000000: 4009ms
```

Comment: Nope. I'm feeling lazy today... :/  Case of the Mondays, I suppose.

Comment: I suspect that getting the ".length" from the result of calling "Object.keys()" is constant-time, but I also suspect that calling "Object.keys()" is linear in the number of properties.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/object-keys-performance 100 times as many items in the object causes it to be 200 times as slow on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, @pimvdb -- that's really sad news. :(  Is there any constant-time key-counting method in Node.JS?

Comment: @BMiner: Not directly I guess - but you could make a helper function that adds/removes/modifies items in the object and keeps track of the length when doing so. Then it's just a matter of fetching the stored length when you need it.

Comment: @BMiner you can keep count manually using proxies. But that creates overhead elsewhere. Yes `.length` is O(n)

Comment: You could probably build a C++ module for this :D

Comment: I now see I stated 100 times as much, but in fact it's 1000 times as much that causes it to be 2000 times as slow. But it still means a non-constant time algorithm.

Comment: @pimvdb If it's 1000 or 10000000 times as much, it should not be noticeably slower at all. That's what constant time means. I like your suggestion about keeping track manually - That's what I'll do for my particular app... makes me sad, though

Comment: @Raynos - you're saying the .length is also O(n)? Getting the length property of an Array?

Comment: @BMiner sorry I meant Yes `Object.keys(o).length` is O(n). `.length` on an array is O(1).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See the source, specifically `GetLocalElementKeys`

[v8 objects.cc](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/objects.cc)

Comment: I'm too lazy to do this. English, please. I'd gladly accept your answer.  :P

Comment: Depending on what the object contains they do different things, worst case seems to be doing 1 for loop through all the elements.

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of research, there is no way to determine the number of keys in a JavaScript Object in constant time, at least not in Node... and not quite yet.  Node internally keeps track of this information, but it does not expose it, since there is no method to do so in ECMA-262 5th.

It's worth noting that Harmony (ECMA version 6) may natively support Maps and Sets. Not sure what the spec for these will turn out to be.

I am told that we need to bring this up with TC39 committee.

Bug report for V8: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1800

Answer (score 2):

*ECMA 6 harmony* introduces `Map` and `Set` classes which you can probably utilize (in the future :)

```
var map = new Map;
map.set('a', 'b');
console.log(map.size); // prints 1
```

I believe it should have complexity O(1), not tried though. You can run it in node 0.11+ via `node --harmony script.js`.

---

Another way is to use `Proxy` class which also has been added in *harmony*.