# Get Length of json Data

Tags: javascript, json

i have this json data and i want to get length of this json data and also of css

my json data is shown here

```
jso({tag:"div",css:{backgroundColor:"red"},html:"abc"})
```

i have pass this in function

```
 function jso(data){
    alert(data.length)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "length"?  How many characters are in it?  Is this stored in a string?

Comment: this data is having length 3 Like this

Comment: So how many properties the object has?

Comment: no this is not stored as string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over the data using jQuery counting how many iterations you did do the following:

```
var data = {tag:"div",css:{backgroundColor:"red"},html:"abc"};

var count = 0;
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    count++;
});
```

[See jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/x9Xtn/)

To iterate over the data using JavaScript only counting how many iterations you did do the following:

```
var data = {tag:"div",css:{backgroundColor:"red"},html:"abc"};

var count = 0;
var key;
for(key in data)
{
    var value = data[key];
    count++;
}
```

[​See jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MER2A/)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not a valid JSON object

```
{
  "tag": "div",
  "css": {
     "backgroundColor":"red"
  },
  "html":"abc"
}
```

However proper JSON object don't have a length attribute, so you need to iterate over them to calculate the length.

Answer (score 1):

i know what u mean u just need to loop over your object with a counter variable

```
var x = {tag:"div",css:{backgroundColor:"red"},html:"abc"}

function objectLength(obj){

var counter = 0;

for(var i in obj)
{
counter +=1;
}
return counter
}
```

use it like this

```
alert(objectLength(x))
```