# javascript push key value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, key-value

In my mind I want to push a key-value on array.

Say for example in PHP this is done like this:

```
$err = array();
function check($k,$v) {
  $err[$k] = $v; 
}
```

How is this done exactly in JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: @FelixKling - any string send as parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript key/value pair support in ***[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)***, not in ***[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)***

**Insert Element:**

```
var arr= [1,2,3],
    result = {};

for(var key in arr) {
   result[key] = arr[key]; // in this case key will be 0,1,2 i.e index of array element
}
```

**Check that a key exists:**

```
function checking(k, v) {
  if(result.k != null || result.k !=  undefined) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

According to your function:

```
var err = {}; // not array, should be object
function check(k,v) {
  err[k] = v; // or err.k = v;
}
```

**More on insert:**

```
var x = [];

x.some = 'some'; // OK; arrays are objects
x['some'] = 'some'; // exactly the same
```

**Get value:**

```
x.home; // give 'some'
x['home']; // give 'some'
```

**Count length:**

If you want to get length of an array you have to use `.length`.

For example:

```
x.length; // will return 1
```

And if you want to count the length of an Object:

```
var obj = {a: 'XYZ', b: 'PQR'};

Object.keys(obj).length; // will return 2
```

**To Delete item:**

if you want to remove an item from an Object:

```
delete obj[key];
```

to delete an item from an array:

```
delete arr[index]; // index is position of the element within array
```

also to remove array element you can do

```
arr.splice(0,2); // splice(index, howmany, [item1, item2, ...., itemx])
                 // in this example from start 2 items will delete
```

Comment: Gracias por esta. One more to ask, what is the equivalent of php count() in JS? I tested that .length doesn't fit in here.

Answer (score 2):

You use an object. And do it in much the same way.

```
var $err = {};
function check($k, $v) {
     $err[$k] = $v;
}
```

Granted, that's not an array though.

Do take note that you can actually do this in Javascript arrays, and the interpreter will let you.

```
var $err = []; // an array
function check($k, $v) {
    $err[$k] = $v;
}
```

But you're not really pushing to the array, but rather extending the array **object**. You can check this out with this:

```
var foo = [];
foo['hello'] = 'world';

console.log(foo);            // []
console.log(foo['hello']);   // 'world'
console.log(foo.hello);      // 'world'
console.log(foo.length);     // 0
```

... so best to watch out for this gotcha. :D

Comment: you can remove the `$` now. it's not required in JS :D

Comment: @Joseph ~ Yup, I know. But it adds to the dramatic, oh-my-gosh-so-similar effect! **dun dun duuuuun!** :D

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan Gracias por esta. One more to ask, what is the equivalent of php `count()` in JS? I tested that `.length` doesn't fit in here.

Comment: For arrays, that just equates to `.length`. For objects, that's a different beast altogether though. The same question has been asked here, so best to check the solutions posted there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip