# JSON array get length using jQuery or javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I know there are many similar questions to this. But any of them doesn't work for me.

I have a json array which the whole structure is like this:

[image]

The array the i want to get is this:

[image]

The structure of that json array is:

[image]

I want to get the length of that json array. In the image case above it is **4**.
What I tried so far is this:

```
console.log( $( data.studentMockBeanMap ).size() );
console.log( $(data.studentMockBeanMap ).length );.
```

Which both returns **1**

I also try this one:

```
var x = JSON.stringify(data.studentMockBeanMap);
console.log( x.length );
```

Which returns **2257**, which IMO it also returns the sum of all json object.

**How can I only the size on the image i boxed above?**

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object with several properties. This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip

Comment: @EfrainReyes I see. Is there another way than the link you gave? the solution there doesn't support lower version of browser like FF3 that is quite a toll.

Comment: The marked answer in particular is for newer browsers, but did you check the other answers on that link, and the corresponding comment threads?

Comment: By the way, check out this link as well, that approach may work with older browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369971/2563028

Comment: One more thing before leaving for tonight (it's late here, sorry if I'm commenting too much): The reason why you get 2257 in your last code snippet isn't because that's the sum of all json objects, it's because that's the length of the string generated by converting studentMockBeanMap and all its child objects to a JSON string.

Comment: I'll look into the links you gave. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does the same think as *Object.keys(obj).length*, but without the browser compatibility issue (I think).

What about:

```
var obj = {
    yo: {
         a: 'foo',
         b: 'bar'
    }
    hi: {
        c: 'hello',
        d: 'world',
        e: 'json'
    }
}

var arr = [], len;

for(key in obj) {
    arr.push(key);
}

len = arr.length;

console.log(len) //2
```

OR

```
var arr = [], len;

for(key in obj.hi) {
    arr.push(key);
}

len = arr.length;

console.log(len) //3
```

OR, in your case

```
var arr = [], len;

for(key in studentMockBeanMap) {
    arr.push(key);
} 

len = arr.length;

console.log(len); //4
```

Comment: Ah yes. This is what I did just now. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the lodash library (which has a size function).

http://lodash.com/docs#size

```
_.size({red: 'red', blue: 'blue'}) // 2
```