# Counting object pairs in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

ive got a problem getting parameters from a json chain, the json I got looks something like this

```
[{"aa":"bb","ccc":"ddd","eeee":"ffff","ggggg":"hhhhh","iiiiii":"jjjjjj","kkkkkkk":"lllllll"}]
```

Im trying to count how many pairs there are inside the '{}' but i dont know how. I tried `json.length` and `json[0].length`, the first one gave me back the value '1' and the second one `undefined`.

Comment: Which programming language is this? JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Your json object is an array containing one object. So the length is 1. The object in the array has multiple properties (key/value pairs).

So in most modern browsers (except IE), this would work for you:

```
Object.keys(json[0]).length
```

Check out the answers here of various techniques for iterating/counting properties of an object in JavaScript:

- [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)