# How to get the count of the object(data)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
$.post("@(Url.Action("SelectAction", "ControllerName"))", function(data){
    // How to get the count of the data(object)
});
```

How to get the **count of the data(object)**. I used `data.count` but is returning as "**undefined**".

Comment: Is it an object, or is it in fact a string or array ?

Comment: Are you sure a value is being passed by data?

Comment: `Object.keys(data).length` in newer browsers should work. Otherwise you'll have to iterate the object as length is'nt supported for objects. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the no. of properties in an object, you could use:

> Object.keys(data).length

Or if you want a cross-browser approach, you'll need to loop through the object itself using:

```
var count = 0;

for (i in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as pointed out in other answers (`Object.keys(data).length`).

Don't use a temporary fix if you want cross-browser compatibility however. Use a shim. It's simple enough and will just be better for newer browsers. Old browsers will simply use the shim.

Quick shim:

```
if (!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o) {
  if (o !== Object(o))
    throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on a non-object');
  var k=[],p;
  for (p in o) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) k.push(p);
  return k;
}
```

Source: http://tokenposts.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/javascript-objectkeys-browser.html