# How to parse json in js?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to parse a json object like `{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}` in a loop.

Trying:

```
var inobj = '[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}]';
var obj = eval(inobj);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var key = i;
        var val = obj[key];
        alert (key+' = '+val);
    }
```

But i don't know hot to know `obj.length`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}');

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    alert(key + " = " + obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: Or simply `for (var key in obj) {...}`.

Comment: @FelixKling I prefer the `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) { .. })` approach since it creates a new scope, avoiding the hoisting issues inherent in `for` loops.

Comment: If a new scope is required then yes, it's a nice approach... otherwise, a simple `for` seems to have less overhead.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, in this example a new scope is not necessarily required, but I can just imagine this user's next question being "why when I call `setTimeout` inside my `for` loop does it not work like I expect..." :)

Answer (score 1):

You can count poperties:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

see stack question: [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)