# number of column count in $.each loop

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery script

```
success: function(data) {
                    //$("#divReport").html(CreateReportHTML(data));
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        createDynamicTable($("#tbReport"), key, 5);
                    });    

                    $("#btnViewReport").attr("disabled",false);
                    $("#btnExportToExcel").attr("disabled",false);
                },
```

from the above, "key" is meant for index as you know while "value" has the columns. The values are retirved like value.FirstName, value.LastName etc.

I need to get the number of columns available in "value" from $.each. How will I find it ? I tried value.length, which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to retrieve the number of keys in the 'value' object.

```
Object.keys(value).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of properties/keys of any object in Javascript using `Object.keys()` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) method.
In your case that would be:

```
Object.keys(value).length
```

Reference:

1. [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)
2. [Browser support](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)