# Find out length of an array which is in Object notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is my array

```
var linkArray = {
boothsizeDiv_link: false,
furnishingsprovidedDiv_link: false,
electricalDiv_link: false,
rentalfurnishingsDiv_link: false,
gesgraphicsDiv_link: false,
geslaborDiv_link: false,
contractorDiv_link: false,
carpetingDiv_link: false,
boothlightingDiv_link: false,
javitsDiv_link: false,
boothsealDiv_link: false,
mannequinsDiv_link: false,
calcDiv_link: false
};
```

How to find out this array length? I have googled it but no use..

Comment: It's look like a JSON string, you need to parse it first. But before that correct the notation.

Comment: that's not an array, that's an object

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
Object.keys(linkArray).length
```

Comment: Will not work in IE8 since it has no support for `Object.keys`

Comment: Yeah, but that's a topic for a different question IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i, length = 0;
for(i in linkArray) {
  if(linkArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    length++;
  }
}

// Here you can use length
```

Comment: @Amrenda I checked, it gives 13 as expected [http://jsbin.com/ubelen/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/ubelen/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(linkArray).length
```

but be careful, because this is *NOT* an array, this is a object.

**And beware that it will not work on Internet Explorers below 9.**

In this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) you can see how `getOwnPropertyNames` can be used.

If you want to use it also in Browser that don't support it, you just insert the following snippet in your script, at the beginning:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames || function(obj) {
    var ownProperties = [];
    var current = '';
    for(current in obj) {
      if(linkArray.hasOwnProperty(current)) {
        ownProperties.push(current);
      }
    }
    return ownProperties;
}
```

(I just wrote it, and can't test it at the moment, but it should work)

with this snippet you simulate `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` in browsers that don't have it natively.

And clearly instead of `getOwnPropertyNames` you can also use `keys`

Comment: Array is also and Object in JavaScript. The above will not work because length property is defined for an Array and some other objects in JS but not for "Object".

Comment: Yes, sorry, i pressed "post" prematurely. Editetd to correct it. And yes, every array is an object, but not every object is an array (although you can access the members through the `[]` notation)