# How to get ALL properties of an object without using for-in loop in JavaScript (Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, key

I was trying to get/count properties of an object and found [this QaA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip), and [this cross-browser solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility).

However, `Object.keys` does not always return the same as with `for-in loop`.

```javascript
var obj = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};

// foo, bar
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

// foo, bar
for(var p in obj) {
    console.log(p);
}
```

```javascript
var obj = document.body.style;

// [] <-- empty array
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

// background, backgroundImage, border, fontFamily...
for(var p in obj) {
    console.log(p);
}
```

I'm not sure if objects like `document.body.style` are `enumerable`.

Even if they are, [according to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Examples), we can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead for none-enumerable properties, but it returns an empty array as well.

Can someone explain this? And is it possible to get all properties of objects like `document.body.style` without for-in loop?

## edit

Oops, I was testing this with Firefox only. Until Osiris posts a comment, I realized this only happens to **Firefox** (19 and 20 which is the latest version). IE 9, Opera 12, Chrome 26, Safari 5 are all fine.

Comment: In Chrome's DevTools, `Object.keys(document.body.style)` returns an array of 394 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of `document.body.style` are not enumerable in Firefox. You can easily test that using:

```
document.body.style.propertyIsEnumerable('background'); // FF: false, WebKit: true
```

Comment: since all other browsers return some properties, is this considered to be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of properties you want to count.

**for...in**

Iterates through all *enumerable* properties of an object including properties found in the prototype chain.

**Object.keys**

Returns all *enumerable* properties that can be found directly upon the object. Does not consider properties of the prototype chain.

**Object.getOwnPropertyNames**

returns *all* properties, enumerable or not, that can be found directly upon the object. Does not consider properties of the prototype chain.

Depending on the object, those methods can, of course, return different results. What makes this even more complicated is that objects (or prototypes) may have properties that are enumerable in one browser and not in the other.

Comment: As for objects like `document.body.style`, it doesn't matter which method I use, all three methods should return some properties while all other browsers do. I believe this is a bug (it's not fixed till version 20).

Comment: I'd say it's not specified, but can be regarded as a bug. That aside, if your only concern is `document.body.style` you should be free choose between all three, that's right.