# Access previous key/value in for-in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, for-in-loop

I am new to javascript so please excuse me if its something obvious.

Lets say I have a for-in loop as follows...

```
for( var key in myObj ){

   alert("key :" + myObj[key] ); // accessing current key-value pair

   //how do I access previous element here?
}
```

Is it possible to access previous or next key/value pair in for-in loop?

Comment: Why dont you giv it a try..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no direct way. One workaround would be to use a `for` loop over `keys` instead of `for..in` and pick elements by their numeric index:

```
 keys = Object.keys(myObj);
 for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
     current = keys[i];
     previous = keys[i - 1];
     next = keys[i + 1];
     ...
  }
```

Comment: +1. Yes, I think I will use this method and drop for-in loop. I was expecting some straight-forward way to do this in for-in loop.

Comment: @PratikPatel: `for..in` is a bad idea anyways, so yes, do drop it.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using Object.keys() function because of a comment in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889658/2039750 which says,  "This not only iterates through the object but also creates a whole new array with all its keys..."

Comment: @PratikPatel: do not optimize prematurely. Unless your objects have millions of keys, making a new array doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastobj = '';
for( var key in myObj ){
   alert("key :" + myObj[key] ); // accessing current key-value pair

   if(lastobj) {
        //do things with last object here using lastobjs
   }
lastobj = myObj[key]
}
```

Give a new value to lastobj last in loop and you will have the value "in memory" during the loop. The `if` statement is mostly because of the first loop run, when lastobj is empty yet.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just say at the end of a loop something like:

```
previousKey = key
```

Then you can use previousKey in your next loop?
This is something I do in my own small scripts, I'm by no means good at scripting but this has worked for me so far.

Answer (score -1):

Try like

```
var prev = '';
for( var key in myObj ){

   alert("key :" + myObj[key] ); // accessing current key-value pair
   if(prev)
      alert('Prev key :'+prev);
   prev = myobj[key];
   //how do I access previous element here?
}
```