# Trouble iterating, and parsing application data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, firebase

I am working on my first AngularJS web-app and have been stuck trying to iterate and parse some data. I am trying to display how many users (and ideally their name) are currently connected to my Firebase, aka `{{users}}`.

I am receiving the following output from AngularFire, but cannot parse or iterate through it.

**Output from `{{users}}`** *(joe and james are both connected to the firebase)*

```
{"b16b":"joe","e109":"james"}
```

**Code within the main controller:**

```
angularFire(fb_userRef, $scope, "users");
```

Attempting to display data and/or iterate through all the users: *(fail)*

```
<div class="panel right" data-role="panel" data-position="right" 
     data-display="overlay" id="right-panel">
<h3>{{users.length}} people here</h3>
<div ng-repeat="usr in users"><h1>YES</h1></div>
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking by your users variable it is a object not an array. Use the key,value syntax of ng-repeat to iterate over it properties

`<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in users"><h1>YES</h1></div>`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly. Is there a similar way to quickly get a count for all of the properties within the object? {{users.length}} seemed like it would work but it does not.

Comment: Not sure about that as the users is not an array.

Comment: This would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip