# Count members in a hash

Tags: typescript

This should be fairly simple, but I just can't get it sorted - I have the following definition:

```
export interface IUnit {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    //further members;
}
export class Unit implements IUnit {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    //...
}

export interface IUnits { [id: string]: IUnit; }
export class Units implements IUnits { [id: string]: Unit; }
```

Now, if I have a variable of the type `IUnits`, e.g.

```
var x: IUnits = { 
    "1": {"id": 1, "name": "First"}, 
    "2": {"id": 2, "name": "Second"}
};
```

, how can I determine the number of it's members? `x.length();` does not work. I guess I could use `for ... in ...`, but this seems horribly inefficient...

Comment: I cannot recommend underscore enough : http://underscorejs.org/#keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a Typescript way that makes this any more readable syntax than the loop you mention and one other option.

In modern browsers, you can easily get the list of keys:

```
var len=Object.keys(x).length;
```

That does create an array though, so you may just want to use the other syntax.

There are a few options discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip) as well.

You may need to filter out properties that contain functions depending on what you're looking for, if for example you had custom event handlers with callbacks.