# how to detect the last for loop step - js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
Object {12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object}
```

and I want to detect the last for loop step in here:

```
for (var i in objs){
   console.log(objs[i]);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by *latest for loop step*?

Comment: The current loop step is always the latest ... Or do you mean you want to detect if you're executing the last step?

Comment: Related: [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/126100/464709)

Comment: How do you define "last" ? -- I'm not sure that there are any guarantees of orders of attribute in an object.

Comment: @Soren just the last step before ending the loop

Comment: @Soren You're right, but the order doesn't matter, if OP just wants to know, when the body of the loop is executed last time before exiting the loop.

Answer (score 2):

you could  use standard object method [Object.keys();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
obj = {12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object};
keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(keys[keys.length - 1]);
console.log(obj[keys[keys.length - 1]]);//if you want that last ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this what you want

```
var latest;
for (var i in objs){
    console.log(objs[i]);
    latest = objs[i];
}
//work with latest
```

Comment: Im not sure, but i think you dont even need to set "latest", `i` is still set to be the last key of the loop so you can just use obj[i] after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since **you cannot control properties' order of an object** (they come in arbitrary order which you cannot define) *the whole idea probably loses* some, or most, if not all, of *its relevance*.

If you don't actually care which property is being processed in that last loop step, here's an example of how you could go:

```
var objs = {12: Object, 13: Object, 14: Object};
var c = 0;
var objsKeys = Object.keys(objs); [12, 13, 14]
for (var i=0; i<obsjKeys.length, i++){
    if (i===(obsjKeys.length -1)) {
        console.log("Last Run of the Loop:");
    }
    console.log(objs[obsjKeys[i]]);
}
```

`Object.keys()` is only available since ES5, which means IE < 9 will not support it. In that case you can do your own implementation of it using `for..in`:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(obj) {
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tempArray.push(key);
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Object.length - 1
```

This will give you the last element..