# How to define a jagged associative array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to define an array which works this way:

```
myArray[0] = 'Volkswagen'
myArray[0][0] = 'Crossfox'
myArray[1] = 'Ford'
myArray[1][0] = 'Focus'
```

I can do by hand but of course it's not the way to do it.
I have a simple array with this:

```
arrayVolks = ['Crossfox', 'Up', 'Golf'];
arrayVolks[name] = 'Volkswagen';
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create the first array with the index with the *name of the **array*** and *then add* the **array**.

I was thinking on some way like this:

```
var myArray = [ arrayVolks[name]: {arrayVolks} ]
```

*(The code immediately over it's more like a pseudo code than actual javascript)*

Is it possible?

Thank you in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't create array like this in javascript:

```
myArray[0] = 'Volkswagen'
myArray[0][0] = 'Crossfox'
myArray[1] = 'Ford'
myArray[1][0] = 'Focus'
```

how about using `Object` instead?

```
var obj = {};
obj['Volkswagen'] = ['Crossfox', 'Up', 'Golf'];
obj['Ford'] = ['Focus'];

// get all brands
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

// print all "Volkswagen"
console.log(obj['Volkswagen']);
console.log(obj.Volskwagen);
```

Comment: Am i being able to use the Object.keys(obj).length? I know it works, but is it the correct way of doing it? (to access the length)

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889658/2048417 - yes. But be advised that `Object.keys` doesn't work in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

A jagged array is an array of arrays.

By doing `myArray[0] = 'Volkswagen'` you set the first element of the root array to a string so you are violating the structure already.

An alternate data structure would probably be better, but if you wish to have a jagged array you may define a structure where the first element of each nested array is the make while the other elements will be the models.

```js
var cars = [
    ['Volkswagen', 'Crossfox'],
    ['Ford', 'Focus']
];

console.log(cars[0][0]); //Volkswagen
console.log(cars[0][1]); //Crossfox
```

Comment: I have programmed in php so i guess i've mistaken how it works in javascript.

Comment: @Yacomini FYI - The equivalent of associative arrays in JavaScript are plain objects.