# Get data from API and continue when done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, underscore.js

I have a problem with looping get request to apis in nodejs. I want to fetch data from multiple endpoints and continue when all request are done. I tried something like this but its running async and logging an empty array. Any tips how know for sure when all requests are ready?

```
var api_endpoints = { "1": "url1", "2": "url2", "3": "url3" };

var allApiSources = [];
_.each(api_endpoints, function (val, key) {
    request(val, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            _.each(data.url, function (val, key) {
                allApiSources.push(value);
            });
        }
    });
});
console.log(allApiSources); // []
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1. use promises or 2. use asyncjs or 3. use a counter to count how many values have been pushed to the array, and when they're all done, you'll have all the data (though, I wouldn't push to the array if the order is important - because asynchronous code is asynchronous)

Comment: Order is not important here :)

Comment: I cant really use a counter because the amount of values is dynamic and changes often.

Comment: you're using `_.each` ... so ... why is a counter inappropriate?

Comment: Well, for that reason you can use api_endpoints.length since you don't know the exact length

Comment: except api_endpoints is not an Array @Lys

Comment: My bad then you gotta do smth like Object.keys(obj).length as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip

Comment: in `allApiSources.push(value);` ... where does `value` come from?

Comment: is `data.url` an array, or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `promises`, and `Object.values`

One assumption ... data.url is an Object, not an array

Another assumption is that in your original code `allApiSources.push(value);` should've been `allApiSources.push(val);`

```
var api_endpoints = { "1": "url1", "2": "url2", "3": "url3" };

Promise.all(Object.values(api_endpoints).map(value => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(value, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            // you can remove the Object.values call if data.url is an Array
            return Object.values(data.url);
        }
        reject(error || response.statusCode);
    });
})))
.then(results => [].concat(...results)) // flattens the array of arrays
.then(allApiSources => {
    console.log(allApiSources);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising :)

Comment: ahhh, I see what you did there :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the async npm, since the calls are asynchronous you will not be able to print the values, the async module lets you run multiple async calls and then maps the result to a single array

http://caolan.github.io/async/

```
async.map(['url1','url2','url3'], request, function(err, allApiSources) {
      console.log(allApiSources); // []

    // allApiSources is now an array of responses for each request
});
```

Comment: wow ... async handles the response.statusCode, parses the body and extracts the values for you!! how smart is that!!!

Comment: hehe..also is there a way to get the map values from array/object or do I have to manually write all urls there?

Comment: async.map will accept an OBJECT according to the documentation - there's much detail left out of this answer to explain how it could work for you!

Comment: `Object.values({ "1": "url1", "2": "url2", "3": "url3" })` => `['url1','url2','url3']`