# Getting the .length of a object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the "lenght" of "enemies"? I have tried many ways, but I haven´t been able to do it. I want to use the number to loop thru the enemies. I tried Object.key() and many variations, but I don't quiet get how to implemente it, or if I am going on the right direction.

```
var rooms = {
"start": {
    "description": "You are in a dark, cold place and you see a light to <b>north</b>\
 and you hear the sound of running water to the <b>west</b>",
    "directions": {
        "north": "clearing1",
        "west": "bridge1"
    },
    "enemies": {
      "enemy1": "enemiesDB[0]",
      "enemy2": "enemiesDB[1]"
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**
I change the code to be an array which solved the problem.

```
    var rooms = {
"start": {
    "description": "You are in a dark, cold place and you see a light to <b>north</b>\
 and you hear the sound of running water to the <b>west</b>",
    "directions": {
        "north": "clearing1",
        "west": "bridge1"
    },
    "enemies": [enemiesDB[0], enemiesDB[1]]
}
```

Then I was able to use it in a loop like this...

```
rooms.start.enemies.length
```

Thanks @NickCordova!

Comment: What do you want "length" to mean? There's no native "length" for plain objects.

Comment: Object.keys(rooms.start.enemies).length;

Comment: What you are asking for is a duplicate of [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126100/218196), but what you actually want to do is a duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312459/218196). Getting the number of properties won't really help you to iterate over them.

Comment: `"enemiesDB[0]"~ <-- please tell me you are not using eval when you reference that.

Comment: I just want to get the number of values contain in "enemies" so I can run a for loop and print the names.

Comment: @Chris: Iterating over properties doesn't require getting the number of properties. See the duplicate.

Comment: "enemies[0]" is referencing an object in another array like "enemies = [skeleys, troll, mummy]"

Comment: @FelixKling I checking out the posts you provided.

Comment: You'd be better for keeping "enemies" an array so that you can use the built-in array methods. enemies : [ enemiesDB[0], enemiesDB[1] ]

Comment: @NickCordova It worked like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Objects doesn't have a length, however you can use Object.keys to get an array of the enumerable own keys of an object, and read the length of that array.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, but how do I implement it?

Comment: Object.keys(rooms.start.enemies).length

Answer (score 2):

**Enemies** is an **[`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)** which does not have a **`length`**, i guess you want

**`Object.keys(rooms.start.enemies).length;`**

**DEMO**

```js
var rooms = {
  "start": {
    "description": "You are in a dark, cold place and you see a light  and you hear the sound of running water to the <b>west</b>",
    "directions": {
      "north": "clearing1",
      "west": "bridge1"
    },
    "enemies": {
      "enemy1": "enemiesDB[0]",
      "enemy2": "enemiesDB[1]"
    }
  }
};
console.log(Object.keys(rooms.start.enemies).length);
```

Comment: I get this error when implementing the code...my code "$('#game-text').append(Object.keys(rooms.start.enemie).length);"  the error "caught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: which line throws the error

Comment: you are missing an s in enemie