# How to find the total no of keys present in the object along with the inner nested objects which is assigned to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Using this data, how do I find the count of keys for the Customer object and all child element objects?

```
const Customer = {
"Profile": {
    "A1": {
        "A2": "",
        "A3": "E",
        "A4": "",
        "A5": {
            "Cus": "",
            "Bil": ""
        },
        "Services": [{
            "vA": {
                "Status": 2,
                "Switch-CLLi": "",
                "PLIST": [{
                    "Status": "",
                    "Price": 0
                }, {
                    "Status": "",
                    "Price": 40
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    "B1": {
        "B2": 953108717,
        "B3": "04"
    }
}}
```

Comment: Result should be count of the available keys .

Comment: Hey, Can you edit the question to be in correct format, current JSON is not readable. Also what things have you tried and what is not working ?

Comment: const Customer =  { "Profile" : {"A1" : {"A2" : "", "A3" : "E","A4" : "","A5" : {"Cus" : "", "Bil" : ""
              }, "Services" : [ {  "vA" : {"Status" : 2,  "Switch-CLLi" : "", "PLIST" : [ {
                    "Status" : "",
                   
                    "Price" : 0
                   
                  }, {
                     "Status" : "",
                   
                    "Price" : 40
                  }
                   ]
     }
     }
     },
     
     "B1":{ "B2" : 953108717,           "B3" : "04"
     }
     }
     }

Comment: This is the data i have and i need the total count of keys present, including with nested objects keys i had tried --> console.log(Object.keys(obj1.Profile).length) Here obj1 is the reference of Customer variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

you can user recursion for this.

```
const countKeys = (obj, result) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
   result.sum+= keys.length;
   result.keys = [...result.keys, ...keys];
   keys.forEach(key => {
      if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object')
       result= countKeys(obj[key],result);
   })
   return result;
};
```

call this method in you method

```
const totalKeys = countKeys(yourObject, { sum: 0, keys: []});
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks alot Sujit.And one more how can we get all the keys names from these

Comment: updated. Please mark as answer if this solves your problem

Comment: It is first looping to all the main keys and then it's taking the nested keys, can we have a sequential order of the keys like when reading, if a nested object is found then it should also print the nested object keys along with the main key names . Eg:- Suppose from the json sample A5 key has nested object(Cus and Bil) then it should go into the netetd object print the keys and then next it will go to other key called Services.

Comment: Modify the function to do that. I have given you the basic approach

Comment: Stackoverflow is used to get the basic approach to solve your problem. use it to create your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to reinvent the wheel and find a good library for data processing and learn that. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for almost everything. It's pretty powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could solve your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const count = (data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ property, context }) => {
    if (typeof property === 'string') {
      context[property] = (context[property] || 0) + 1;
    }
  }
})(data, {});

const Customer = { Profile: { A1: { A2: '', A3: 'E', A4: '', A5: { Cus: '', Bil: '' }, Services: [{ vA: { Status: 2, 'Switch-CLLi': '', PLIST: [{ Status: '', Price: 0 }, { Status: '', Price: 40 }] } }] }, B1: { B2: 953108717, B3: '04' } } };

console.log(count(Customer));
// => { B3: 1, B2: 1, B1: 1, Price: 2, Status: 3, PLIST: 1, 'Switch-CLLi': 1, vA: 1, Services: 1, Bil: 1, Cus: 1, A5: 1, A4: 1, A3: 1, A2: 1, A1: 1, Profile: 1 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)