# How do I check if an object has only one property or only two properties and no other property in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to check if an object has only one property or only two properties and no other property in javascript.

Suppose I have an object like this.

```
const obj1 = {
   a : 'something'
}
```

OR

```
const obj2 = {
  a : 'somthing',
  b : 'somthing else'
}
```

Now how do I check if obj1 has only a and no other property?
Also, how do check if obj2 has only a and b and no other property?
Thanks for your time

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip

Comment: Key/values are referenced by `:`, not `=` - and you have missing commas...

Comment: By the way, you need to add commas between two property declarations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
Object.keys(obj1).length == 1 && obj1.a
```

and

```js
Object.keys(obj2).length == 2 && obj2.a && obj2.b
```

both utilize the number of keys.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following countobjkey function:

```
<script>
function countobjkey(var1)
{let size=0;
for(let k in var1) {
  size++
}
return(size);
}



var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25};
var car = {engine:"X4", brand:"Toyota", cc:'1300', color:'black'};

alert(countobjkey(person));
alert(countobjkey(car));



</script>
```