# Is this O(N) approach the only way of avoiding a while loop when walking this linked list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, linked-list

I have a data structure that is essentially a linked list stored in state. It represents a stream of changes (patches) to a base object. It is linked by key, rather than by object reference, to allow me to trivially serialise and deserialise the state.

It looks like this:

```js
const latest = 'id4' // They're actually UUIDs, so I can't sort on them (text here for clarity)
const changes = {
  id4: {patch: {}, previous: 'id3'},
  id3: {patch: {}, previous: 'id2'},
  id2: {patch: {}, previous: 'id1'},
  id1: {patch: {}, previous: undefined},
}
```

At some times, a user chooses to run an expensive calculation and results get returned into state. We do not have results corresponding to every change but only some. So results might look like:

```js
const results = {
  id3: {performance: 83.6},
  id1: {performance: 49.6},
}
```

Given the changes array, I need to get the results *closest* to the tip of the changes list, in this case `results.id3`.

I've written a while loop to do this, and it's perfectly robust at present:

```js
    let id = latest
    let referenceId = undefined
    while (!!id) {
      if (!!results[id]) {
        referenceId = id
        id = undefined
      } else {
        id = changes[id].previous
      }
    }
```

The approach is O(N) but that's the pathological case: I expect a long changelist but with fairly frequent results updates, such that you'd only have to walk back a few steps to find a matching result.

### While loops can be vulnerable

Following the great work of Gene Krantz (read his book "Failure is not an option" to understand why NASA never use recursion!) I try to avoid using while loops in code bases: They tend to be susceptible to inadvertent mistakes.

For example, all that would be required to make an infinite loop here is to do `delete changes.id1`.

So, I'd like to avoid that vulnerability and instead fail to retrieve any result, because not returning a performance value can be handled; but the user's app hanging is REALLY bad!

### Other approaches I tried

#### Sorted array O(N)

To avoid the while loop, I thought about sorting the `changes` object into an array ordered per the linked list, then simply looping through it.

The problem is that I have to traverse the whole changes list first to get the array in a sorted order, because I don't store an ordering key (it would violate the point of a linked list, because you could no longer do O(1) insert).

It's not a heavy operation, to push an id onto an array, but is still O(N).

### The question

Is there a way of traversing this linked list without using a while loop, and without an O(N) approach to convert the linked list into a normal array?

Comment: Do your change keys ever get deleted, or do they only get added? Does insertion always happen at one end of the linked list or also in the middle?

Comment: insertion always happens at the end of the linked list; but undo operations can also happen to remove the latest change from the end.

Comment: So then it is like a *stack*, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to append at the end and possibly remove from the end, the required structure is a *stack*. In JavaScript the best data structure to implement a stack is an array -- using its `push` and `pop` features.

So then you could do things like this:

```js
const changes = []; 

function addChange(id, patch) {
    changes.push({id, patch});
}

function findRecentMatch(changes, constraints) {
    for (let i = changes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const {id} = changes[i];
        if (constraints[id]) return id;
    }
}

// Demo
addChange("id1", { data: 10 });
addChange("id2", { data: 20 });
addChange("id3", { data: 30 });
addChange("id4", { data: 40 });

const results = {
  id3: {performance: 83.6},
  id1: {performance: 49.6},
}

const referenceId = findRecentMatch(changes, results);
console.log(referenceId);  // id3
```

Depending on what you want to do with that `referenceId` you might want `findRecentMatch` to return the *index* in `changes` instead of the change-id itself. This gives you the possibility to still retrieve the `id`, but also to clip the `changes` list to end at that "version" (i.e. as if you popped all the entries up to that point, but then in one operation).

Comment: This is much more elegant, thank you @trincot. In my case, I also need O(1) access to the change values (which I foolishly hadn't mentioned) but I could maintain a map of indices for that. So I think this is a better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

While writing out the question, I realised that rather than avoiding a while-loop entirely, I can add an execution count and an escape hatch which should be sufficient for the purpose.

This solution uses `Object.keys()` which is strictly O(N) so not *technically* a correct answer to the question - but it is very fast.

If I needed it faster, I could restructure `changes` as a [`map`](https://www.zhenghao.io/posts/object-vs-map) instead of a general object and access `changes.size` [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58492580/3556110)

```js
    let id = latest
    let referenceId = undefined
    const maxLoops = Object.keys(changes).length
    let loop = 0
    while (!!id && loop < maxLoops) {
      loop++
      if (!!results[id]) {
        referenceId = id
        id = undefined
      } else {
        id = changes[id].previous
      }
    }
```