# Calculating row totals of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsreport

I am trying to calculate row and column total for the following dataset. I am using Jsreport

```
    "incidentTypes": {
        "Blo": [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        "Ma": [0,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1],
        "Ph": [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1]
    }
```

This is the helper function i used to calculate the row total but I am not sure how to calculate the row total

```
function total(input) {
    var sum = input.reduce((acc,value) => acc+value)
    return sum
}
```

and this how i called in in jsreport

```
  {{#each incidentTypes}} 
  <tr>
    <td>{{@key}} </td>
    {{#each this}}
    <td>{{this}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    <td>{{total this}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Just do it in vanilla js. No need to make things complicated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "This is the helper function i used to calculate the row total but I am not sure how to calculate the row total" Wait, what?

Comment: @Dexygen Sorry, typing error. I calculate the column total but now i want to calculate the row total

Comment: @pilchard, Sorry, typing error. I calculate the column total but now i want to calculate the row total

Answer (score -1):

If the rows are each key of incidentTypes, you just have to count how many keys are in it.

```
function getTotalRows(incidentTypes) {
    return Object.keys(incidentTypes).length
}
```

Based on:
[How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)