# Unable to get length value of an array in Node Red JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node-red

I would like to know the length of an array read inside a function in NodeRed using JavaScript but it is not displaying/returning any value. Can someone help me here?

[image]

Here is the code inside the function block in Node-Red

```
let j = 0;
let array1 = { payload: msg.payload };

j = array1.length;

return j;
```

I do not see any return value for `j`. any help?

I was expecting a value of 50 for `j` to be displayed on NodeRed debug console.

Comment: You are not showing enough of your code for us to be able to help.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Array1 isn’t an array

Comment: `array1` is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It may be wise to peruse some documentation on the basics.

Comment: Sorry, i did not know that array1 is an object. I am a beginner. Can some one help me how to get length or how many items are inside an object ?

Comment: We have many questions about that: [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126100/215552)

Comment: Also Node-RED Function nodes **MUST** return an `msg` object, not a bare value. If `j` was 50 this would be a raw number, the correct return is to set `msg.payload = j` then `return j`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the actual answer to your question. Note these things given below;

1. `let array1 = { payload: msg.payload }` is not an array. It is an object. You cannot find the length of the object by `obj.length`; rather use `Object.keys(array1).length`

If you want to find the **length** (number of properties) of the object then use the following code snippet.

```
let array1 = { payload: msg.payload };
let length = Object.keys(array1).length;
console.log(length);


// Example
let person = {name: "Mehdi", city: "Jamshoro", country: "PK"}
let length = Object.keys(person).length;
console.log(length);

// Output: 3
```

The length of an array can be found in this way:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
console.log(arr.length)

// Output: 6
```

It seems like you are using a `return` statement outside the function. `return` does not work outside the function. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Objects do not have a length; that's why they don't have a `length` property. `Object.keys(obj).length` merely gives the number of properties the object itself defines (not including those defined by any objects further up the prototype chain). So I would say this answer is incorrect in its definition of an object's "length".

Comment: Object length means, the number of properties the object has. `Object.keys(obj).length` return `3` if the object has `3` properties and so.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Asking how long an object is is like asking how wide green is.

Comment: Even after using the below code, I still see a value of 1 instead of 50.
Any reason ?

let length = Object.keys(array1).length;
console.log(length);

Here is what I see as an output of array1 :
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AC7b.png

Comment: @Heretic Monkey , I think you are correct. I always get a value of 1 in the console. Do you know how to solve this ? I am expecting a value of 50